# How do I iterate through table rows and cells in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

If I have an HTML table...say

```
<div id="myTabDiv">
<table name="mytab" id="mytab1">
  <tr> 
    <td>col1 Val1</td>
    <td>col2 Val2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>col1 Val3</td>
    <td>col2 Val4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

How would I iterate through all table rows (assuming the number of rows could change each time I check) and retrieve values from each cell in each row from within JavaScript?

Answer (score 390, accepted):

If you want to go through each row(`<tr>`), knowing/identifying the row(`<tr>`), and iterate through each column(`<td>`) of each row(`<tr>`), then this is the way to go.

```
var table = document.getElementById("mytab1");
for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
   //iterate through rows
   //rows would be accessed using the "row" variable assigned in the for loop
   for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
     //iterate through columns
     //columns would be accessed using the "col" variable assigned in the for loop
   }  
}
```

If you just want to go through the cells(`<td>`), ignoring which row you're on, then this is the way to go.

```
var table = document.getElementById("mytab1");
for (var i = 0, cell; cell = table.cells[i]; i++) {
     //iterate through cells
     //cells would be accessed using the "cell" variable assigned in the for loop
}
```

Comment: ex2, table.cells isnt browser compatible

Comment: @WilliamRemacle  I posted this answer almost 4 years ago.. IE 9 was not even a thought at the time!

Comment: @JohnHartsock I know but I used your solution and figured out that it does not work on IE. It is just a comment to warn the others... I voted up your answer anyway ;-)

Comment: function itTable() {
 document.writeln("itTable");
 var table = document.getElementById("mytab");

 for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
    document.writeln(i);
    for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
       document.writeln(j);
    }  
 }

 document.writeln("end-itTable");
}  Why would this code not let me loop through a table similar to the one above.

Comment: For those (coming here through google) needing a *simple and small* shim for `table.cells` (to patch up some older/IE-oriented code), see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23730355/588079) to [Q: Does Firefox browser not recognize table.cells?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10701076/588079)

Comment: What does the first "row" do in: 
for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {

Comment: Is there a way to assign tags to `<tr>` and `<td>`s of html table generated from dataframe?

Comment: I understood the loop but how to read the value in the cell?

Answer (score 81):

You can consider using jQuery. With jQuery it's super-easy and might look like this:

```
$('#mytab1 tr').each(function(){
    $(this).find('td').each(function(){
        //do your stuff, you can use $(this) to get current cell
    })
})
```

Comment: Can't use jquery...company doesn't allow it.  Don't ask why.

Comment: That's a crazy policy. You could always just copy-n-paste the relevant functions you need from jQuery to your own application code. Unless there's a policy against using other people's code online, but then you wouldn't be here.

Comment: @Judy: Disagree on "crazy policy".... there are plenty of reasons for not using jQuery

Comment: JQuery is something that I have not used in a while and seems at just a glance something that is complex and not easy to get around in. But I think that is just because I have not used it all that much.

Comment: Another reason to disallow JQuery is for embedded websites e.g. I'm using an embedded WiFi chip which only has 250Kb for the whole website. It's a squeeze with all the images as it is.

Comment: jQuery in useless where you need  2-3 functions. It is slow and confusing when coding along with PHP.

Comment: They probably don't allow it because it uses outside resources which aren't controlled by them. It also adds additional overhead and may be slower than default functions... They also change the language from something user-friendly and easy to read into a short-hand style language for most things - not all.. Some of the functions added by JQuery are much nicer to read such as the foreach function with callback - much shorter than writing the same repetitive for each code every time.

Answer (score 42):

Try

```
for (let row of mytab1.rows) 
{
    for(let cell of row.cells) 
    {
       let val = cell.innerText; // your code below
    }
}
```

```js
for (let row of mytab1.rows) 
{
    for(let cell of row.cells) 
    {
       console.log(cell.innerText)
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="myTabDiv">
<table name="mytab" id="mytab1">
  <tr> 
    <td>col1 Val1</td>
    <td>col2 Val2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>col1 Val3</td>
    <td>col2 Val4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

```js
for ( let [i,row] of [...mytab1.rows].entries() ) 
{
    for( let [j,cell] of [...row.cells].entries() ) 
    {
       console.log(`[${i},${j}] = ${cell.innerText}`)
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="myTabDiv">
<table name="mytab" id="mytab1">
  <tr> 
    <td>col1 Val1</td>
    <td>col2 Val2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>col1 Val3</td>
    <td>col2 Val4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: clean I would say

Comment: Notice the "for ... of" in the loops. Would've been nice to have some explanation in your answer.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of

Comment: Simple, elegant and functional, excellent contribution

Comment: Elegant way to do the work without dom/jQuery. How could I finally get all inputs in the cell? (Or all inputs in a row)

Answer (score 17):

```js
var table=document.getElementById("mytab1");
var r=0; //start counting rows in table
while(row=table.rows[r++])
{
  var c=0; //start counting columns in row
  while(cell=row.cells[c++])
  {
    cell.innerHTML='[R'+r+'C'+c+']'; // do sth with cell
  }
}
```

```html
<table id="mytab1">
  <tr>
    <td>A1</td><td>A2</td><td>A3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>B1</td><td>B2</td><td>B3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>C1</td><td>C2</td><td>C3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

In each pass through while loop r/c iterator increases and new row/cell object from collection is assigned to row/cell variables. When there's no more rows/cells in collection, false is assigned to row/cell variable and iteration through while loop stops (exits).

Comment: in previous post:
while (cell=row[r].cells[c++] should be row.cells[c++], row being the current object, and an example for the sth code: mycoldata = cell.innerHTML

Answer (score 13):

Better solution: use Javascript's native `Array.from()` and to convert HTMLCollection object to an array, after which you can use standard array functions.

```
var t = document.getElementById('mytab1');
if(t) {
    Array.from(t.rows || []).forEach((tr, row_ind) => {
        Array.from(tr.cells || []).forEach((cell, col_ind) => {
            console.log('Value at row/col [' + row_ind + ',' + col_ind + '] = ' + cell.textContent);
        });
    });
}
```

You could also reference `tr.rowIndex` and `cell.colIndex` instead of using `row_ind` and `col_ind`.

I much prefer this approach over the top 2 highest-voted answers because it does not clutter your code with global variables `i`, `j`, `row` and `col`, and therefore it delivers clean, modular code that will not have any side effects (or raise lint / compiler warnings)... without other libraries (e.g. jquery). Furthermore, it gives your code access to both `element` and `index` vars rather than just the element, and if you prefer to hide the index, you can just ignore it in the callback arg list.

If you require this to run in an old version (pre-ES2015) of Javascript, `Array.from` can be polyfilled.

Comment: I'm getting `VM150:11 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))` on this line ` Array.from(tr.cells).forEach((cell, col_ind) => {` running on Chrome

Comment: @Cooper is it possible that your table does not have a "rows" child element or some rows do not have any cells? If so, I've updated the example to handle this

Answer (score 5):

Here's one solution using modern Javascript ES6+

```
    const rows = document.querySelector("table")?.rows;
    if (!rows) {
      return;
    }
    Array.from(rows).forEach(row => {
      console.log(row);
      const cells = Array.from(row.cells);
      cells.forEach(cell => {
        console.log(cell);
      });
    });
```

`Array.from()` converts the HTMLCollection of rows and/or cells into a regular Javascript Array which you can iterate through.

Documentation for `table.rows` usage: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/rows

Documentation for `row.cells` usage: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement

Answer (score 3):

If you want one with a functional style, like this:

```
    const table = document.getElementById("mytab1");
    const cells = table.rows.toArray()
                  .flatMap(row => row.cells.toArray())
                  .map(cell => cell.innerHTML); //["col1 Val1", "col2 Val2", "col1 Val3", "col2 Val4"]
```

You may modify the prototype object of HTMLCollection (allowing to use in a way that resembles extension methods in C#) and embed into it a function that converts collection into array, allowing to use higher order funcions with the above style (kind of linq style in C#):

```
    Object.defineProperty(HTMLCollection.prototype, "toArray", {
        value: function toArray() {
            return Array.prototype.slice.call(this, 0);
        },
        writable: true,
        configurable: true
    });
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toArray' of undefined --> This is what I got, when I tried this solution.

Comment: Strange. I tried it again and it worked. I couldn't reproduce the error you pointed, though. Maybe the problem is the browser. I tested using Edge and IE and both did't work. Chrome, Firefox and Safari worked as expected.

Comment: I used chrome too.

Comment: This works for me too. The `Object.defineProperty` obviously has to go before the rest of the code, but it works. @Vineela Thonupunuri did you try it with the code in the correct order?

Answer (score 2):

This solution worked perfectly for me

```
var table = document.getElementById("myTable").rows;
var y;
for(i = 0; i < # of rows; i++)
{    for(j = 0; j < # of columns; j++)
     {
         y = table[i].cells;
         //do something with cells in a row
         y[j].innerHTML = "";
     }
}
```

Comment: Is that even JavaScript? Because your for loop looks somewhat like PHP.

Comment: A lot of languages are surprisingly similar when you know what to look for. PHP would use a $ in front of each variable, this doesn't. var is also a keyword used by JavaScript, not PHP although if they added it I may have missed it. - edit- gah no enter for newline... As I say: Logic is universal. Knowing how to transcribe it into alternate languages is an incredibly useful skill which isn't difficult to learn - we are beings of intellect with excellent pattern matching abilities. Identify the changes between each language or simply use the lexer language definition...

Comment: If you are answering a question `# of rows` doesnt say anything... Please update your answer with the full code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[`.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)** to select all `td` elements, then loop over these with **[`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)**. Their values can be retrieved with **[`.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)**:

```js
const cells = document.querySelectorAll('td');
cells.forEach(function(cell) {
  console.log(cell.innerHTML);
})
```

```html
<table name="mytab" id="mytab1">
  <tr> 
    <td>col1 Val1</td>
    <td>col2 Val2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>col1 Val3</td>
    <td>col2 Val4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If you want to only select columns from a specific row, you can make use of the pseudo-class **[`:nth-child()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)** to select a specific `tr`, optionally in conjunction with the **[child combinator (`>`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator)** (which can be useful if you have a table within a table):

```js
const cells = document.querySelectorAll('tr:nth-child(2) > td');
cells.forEach(function(cell) {
  console.log(cell.innerHTML);
})
```

```html
<table name="mytab" id="mytab1">
  <tr> 
    <td>col1 Val1</td>
    <td>col2 Val2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>col1 Val3</td>
    <td>col2 Val4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Simplest way to modify all cells. I used this for removing cell styles.

Answer (score 2):

**My solution, using es6:**

```js
var table = document.getElementById('mytab1');

var data = [...table.rows].map(row => [...row.cells].map(td => td.innerText));

console.log(data)
```

REFERENCES: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection

Answer (score 1):

Using a single for loop:

```
var table = document.getElementById('tableID');  
var count = table.rows.length;  
for(var i=0; i<count; i++) {    
    console.log(table.rows[i]);    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I leave this just for future reference for **scraping** a specific HTML table column and printing the results.

```
//select what table you want to scrape (is zero based)
//set 0 if there is only one
setTable=0;
//select what column you want to scrape (is zero based)
//in this case I would be scrapping column 2
setColumnToScrape=1;
var table = document.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[setTable];
for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
  col = row.cells[setColumnToScrape];
  document.write(col.innerHTML + "<br>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a different method using the `childNodes` and `HTMLCollection`

```
    <script>
        var tab = document.getElementsByTagName("table")
        for (var val of tab[0].childNodes[1].childNodes.values())
            if (HTMLCollection.prototype.isPrototypeOf(val.children)) {
                for (var i of val.children) {
                    console.log(i.childNodes[0])
                }
            }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pure Javascript

```js
function numberofRow(){
  var x = document.getElementById("mytab1").rows.length;
  document.getElementById("mytab1").innerHTML = x;
}
numberofRow();
```

```html
<div id="myTabDiv">
<table name="mytab" id="mytab1">
  <tr> 
    <td>col1 Val1</td>
    <td>col2 Val2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>col1 Val3</td>
    <td>col2 Val4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

es6:

```
const table = document.getElementById('some-table');
const cells = table.getElementsByTagName('td');

for (let cell of cells) {
   // do something with cell here
}
```

earlier versions:

```
var table = document.getElementById('some-table');
var cells = table.getElementsByTagName('td');
for ( var i in cells ) {
   // do something with cells[i]
}
```

source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName