# Javascript get cells of a table row TR

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to manipulate table cells with javascript, and so far I managed to get into tr-s, by using:

```
var as = document.getElementById('answers['+id+']');
var trs = as.getElementsByTagName("tr");
for (var i in trs)
{ ... }
```

UPDATE: The `as` variable contains a reference to the table.

Inside of the for cycle I wanted to go on the same login line and I have tried:

```
var tds = trs[i].getElementByTagName("td");
```

The problem is that on debugging I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLTableRowElement> has no method 'getElementByTagName' .
```

How could I get into the td-s of the tr-s?

Comment: possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3065342/how-do-i-iterate-through-table-rows-and-cells-in-javascript)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

its `getElementsByTagName` and not `getElementByTagName`

```
var as = document.getElementById('answers['+id+']');
for(var i=0;i<as.rows.length;i++) {
    var trs = as.getElementsByTagName("tr")[i];
    var cellVal=trs.cells[0]
}
```

the variable `cellVal` will give the reference to the first `cell` or `<td>` similarly do for all the cells by increasing the index or putting it in a loop would make it dynamic...

Comment: No need for getElementsByTagName at all. Tables have a rows collection, and rows have a cells collection, so rows = table.rows and the cells for each row is cells = rows[i].cells.

Answer (score 3):

Check spelling of the method you are using to get td i.e.`getElementByTagName`

It should be `getElementsByTagName`.
This should work fine as the way you are trying to fetch.

Check [Manipulating the table with DOM and CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/traversing_an_html_table_with_javascript_and_dom_interfaces) for more info.