# empty cell value in Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am creating `GridView` by creating `DataTable` and setting it as a `Datasource` of `GridView`, similar to

[add new row in gridview after binding C#, ASP.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19485909/add-new-row-in-gridview-after-binding-c-asp-net)

After calling `DataBind()` I cannot access values of the cells as `Text` attribute is empty for every cell, however everything is displayed on the page.

I have already tried:

[How to get cell value from a gridview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8665176/how-to-get-cell-value-from-a-gridview)

but `Text` attribute is also empty, and

[How to get cell value in GridView (WITHOUT using cell index)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19496204/how-to-get-cell-value-in-gridview-without-using-cell-index)

throws exception as `DataItem` is null. Any ideas what am I missing?

Comment: show your logic of implementation

Comment: Never mind, one of the methods was overriding cell values :/

Comment: `((System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label)(GridView.Rows[i].FindControl("lblName"))).Text.ToString();` is working fine now, however `DataItem` is still null and `GridView.Rows[i].Cells[j].Text` is empty. weird.

Comment: Without looking your code hard to guess what could be the issue. Will be helpful if you can share the code snippet. However make sure that you are binding text box something like this

<asp:textbox id="YourControlID" runat="Server" xmlns:asp="#unknown"> Text='<%# Bind("ColumnName") %>' /></asp:textbox>

Answer (score 0):

You can use Gridview Row DataBound event for this because you want to get the record just after gridview bind
Like
check this [video](http://dotprogramming.blogspot.com/2015/05/how-to-delete-row-of-gridview-using.html)

Comment: You should put relevant snippets from that article into your answer, in case the link goes dead.