# How to validate dynamically created select boxes in javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a html table where the rows are being added dynamically by a javascript function. I have a select box to select the product name in each row. Its working fine.

Now I want to validate the selectbox. I got no clue how to do it. The values in the textboxes shouldn't be selected more than once in the upcoming rows.

I want to show an alert msg like "The product you selected is already selected" onSelect and change the selected value to --Select--- .

See it in [action here](http://jsfiddle.net/nKkhW/14/)

Comment: oops! sorry..my mistake,I apologize that.. its select box not checkbox..! Edited now..thanks

Comment: `The values in the textboxes` OR `The values in the in selectboxes` should not be selected more than once???

Comment: the values of the select boxes shouldn't be selected more than once.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't want to allow multiple select boxes to hold same value.
Well in the `insSpec()` method, you can iterate for the existing rows i.e select boxes and capture those values.Then you can check that is it already selected or not using `selected` property of all the select boxes.

**UPDATE**

```
var table = document.getElementById("mytab1");
for (var i = 0, cell; cell = table.cells[i]; i++) {
     //iterate through cells
     for (var j = 0, cell2; cell2 = table.cells[j]; j++) {
     //check already selected selectboxes have same value or not
     //compare only selected select boxes
     if(cell.getElementsByTagName('select')[0].selected && cell2.getElementByTagName('select')[0].selected){
         //compare values of both cell's select boxes using value property and alert message                  
    }         
}
```

Please don't directly copy paste this code.This is just a way to do the stuff.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3065389/1130032)

Comment: Yes, I don't want to allow select boxes to hold the same value . One product should be selected only once. If it is selected again, the user should get an alert and the selected value should get empty

Comment: So have you tried to implement the above logic in your code ?

Comment: I couldn't understand what u exactly mean, can you give me an example or something ?