# Does Firefox browser not recognize table.cells?

Tags: javascript, firefox, cells

I have the following JavaScript code.

---

```
var myCellCollection = document.getElementById('myTbl').cells;
```

---

This works well in IE and it returns a collection of table cells. But the same line returns "undefined" in Firefox. I am using IE 9 and Firefox 12.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `document.getElementById("myTbl").getElementsByTagName('td')`;

Comment: Thanks. That looks to be a better way to do it. The W3C reference states that Firefox supports this [link](w3schools.com/jsref/coll_table_cells.asp). Also, trying tableObject.cells works in case of this example in Firefox [link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_table_cells)

Comment: That's not a "W3C reference".  It's w3schools.  Which is often wrong, and is definitely wrong in this case.  Your example there is looking on .cells on a table _row_, which is in fact supported by all browsers.

Comment: @BorisZbarsky: Yes, its w3schools. Sorry for the wrong notation there. But what I was telling is to try that example by changing the  _alert_ to `alert(document.getElementById("myTable").cells);` And it works well!

Comment: I just tried editing it as you describe, and in Firefox the alert shows `undefined`, as expected.

Comment: I tried it again and I get the alert as "2". I am unable to upload a screen shot because of restrictions, but I will look for a way to share it with you. Is is that Firefox stores this data somewhere and if I run the code with `document.getElementById("myTable").rows[0].cells` for the first time and with `document.getElementById("myTable").cells` for the second time then it shows the same result from a store. I will verify this on a different machine later in the day.

Comment: @BorisZbarsky: Got it! You are right. The result I am getting is when the _HTML_ is not updated. You need to press the "Edit and click me >>" button after every edit. My bad. Sorry.

Answer (score 4):

Stumbled into this today whilst porting an older Internet Explorer app.

**Warning:**
`container.getElementsByTagName('tagname')` returns *ALL* the elements inside `container` that matches the query `tagname`.

Thus `table.getElementsByTagName('td')` will return all `td`'s *including* those of nested tables!
However `table.cells` doesn't do that (where implemented).

Also, obviously, it won't match `th`. So those cells are not in returned collection, optionally leading to the 'problem'  of how to resolve their order relative to the td's...

To shim the expected functionality of `table.cells` (returning *both* `th` and `td` in DOM-order), I wrote the following simple function:

```
function tableCells(t){
   if(t.cells) return t.cells; // use internal routine when supported
   for(var a=[], r=t.rows, y=0, c, x; t=r[y++];){
      for(c=t.cells, x=0; t=c[x++]; a.push(t));
   } 
   return a;
}
```

<sup>Alternatively, using 'single return' by 'if-else' packs to the same size *exactly*, yet the above gzips smaller. PS: I tried `concat`-ting the `table.rows[X].cells`, but that didn't work (although I wouldn't feel safe doing so anyways)</sup>

**Usage example:**
`var identifier = tableCells( /*reference to table (or thead/tbody/tfoot) here*/ );`
It will return an array (not a live collection) like the result from `table.cells`.

Hope this helps someone