# javascript: looping through all cells in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i'm trying to loop through all the cells in a table and do a comparison on the value.

```
            var table = document.getElementById("assignedvlans");
            alert(table);
            alert($('#assignedvlans tbody tr').length);
            for (var i = 0, cell; cell = table.cells[i]; i++) {
                 //iterate through all cells in table.
                 alert('in the loop');
                 alert(cell.val());
                 if (cell.val == IdforVlanToAdd)
                 {
                    alert('This vlan is already associated with the port.');
                    $bexit = true;
                    break;
                 }                  
            }
```

When i test this code, the alert(table) code is working - it returns "object HTMLTableElement" and the alert for the table lengths returns 4, which is also correct. 
But the alert statements inside the loop never happen.
Can you tell me where i'm going wrong with the loop control? 
Thanks.

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: table.cells won't work because the .cells are part of .rows not table directly.

Comment: Also `cell` is not a jQuery object, so it won't have a `val()` method (it's also not an `input` of any kind, so you probably want `text()` after making it a jQuery object), and I'm assuming that `cell.val` is a typo..? And why are you mixing jQuery and plain-JavaScript approaches? (It works, but it can make things more complicated.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`table` contains `rows[]`, which themselves contain `cells[]`. You can't get the `cells[]` directly from the `table`.

You could use `table.getElementsByTagName('td')` as a shortcut, provided there are no nested tables.

Otherwise, you should loop through each of the `rows[]` and in that loop you can loop through the `cells[]`.

```
var table = document.getElementById('assignedvlans'),
    rows = table.rows, rowcount = rows.length, r,
    cells, cellcount, c, cell;
for( r=0; r<rowcount; r++) {
    cells = rows[r].cells;
    cellcount = cells.length;
    for( c=0; c<cellcount; c++) {
        cell = cells[c];
        // now do something.
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried your code, but when i do an alert(cell.text); everything is coming back as undefined.

Comment: That's because `cell.text` is undefined. If you want the text content, try `cell.firstChild.nodeValue` (if the text is the only thing there) or `text = (cell.textContent || cell.innerText)` if there may be HTML there too.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this :

```
        var $table = $('#assignedvlans tbody td');
        $.map($table,function(){
             if ($(this).text() == IdforVlanToAdd)
             {
                alert('This vlan is already associated with the port.');
                return;
             }   
        });
```

Comment: And what if there is a table inside the table?

Comment: It is not the case in this question.

Comment: Because it would be an important part of the question, and the asker didn't mention that. Your answer is good BTW.

Comment: sdespont, i'm getting the error "Syntax error: unlabelled break must be inside loop or switch".  I'm assuming that I keep the for loop and add your code inside the loop..?

Comment: Yes, it is right. I copy/paste your conditional code without seeing that it contained a break instruction. I have updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're not getting *any* alerts inside the loop is your `for` loop is not structured correctly. It quits immediately because the assignment `cell = table.cells[i]` returns false.

Comment: No, it quits immediately because `table.cells[i]` returns undefined (which is falsy). If it were true, it would be an infinite loop.

Comment: For those (coming here through google) needing a *simple and small* shim for `table.cells` (to patch up older/IE-oriented code), see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23730355/588079) to [Q: Does Firefox browser not recognize table.cells?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10701076/588079)

Answer (score 0):

```
var myDataArr = [];
$('#dynamic_cards tr').each(function(){
    $(this).find('td').each(function(){
        myDataArr.push($(this).text());
    });
});
console.log(myDataArr);
```