# Looping through badly formatted HTML Tables Code jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, sorting

So I have an html table that is being generated by my client. I have zero interest in changing how they generate this code at this time it and neither do they.

```
<TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
        <TR HEIGHT=16>
            <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>
                <B><FONT style=FONT-SIZE:10pt FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000>Chef's Selections for Tuesday, April 25, 2017</FONT></B>
            </TD>
        </TR>
    </TABLE>
    <TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
        <TR HEIGHT=14>
            <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>
                <B><FONT style=FONT-SIZE:8pt FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000>SPRING FLING! Please ask us about our Bell's Beer Pairing! May 22nd!</FONT></B>
            </TD>
        </TR>
    </TABLE>
    <TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
        <TR HEIGHT=19>
            <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>
                <B><FONT style=FONT-SIZE:12pt FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000>Soups</FONT></B>
            </TD>
        </TR>
    </TABLE>
    <TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
        <TR HEIGHT=14>
            <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>
                <FONT style=FONT-SIZE:8pt FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000>Beef Vegetable</FONT>
            </TD>
        </TR>
    </TABLE>
    <TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
        <TR HEIGHT=14>
            <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>
                <FONT style=FONT-SIZE:8pt FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000>Cream of Tomato</FONT>
            </TD>
        </TR>
    </TABLE>
    <TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
        <TR HEIGHT=19>
            <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>
                <B><FONT style=FONT-SIZE:12pt FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000>Lunch Selections</FONT></B>
            </TD>
        </TR>
    </TABLE>
    <TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
        <TR HEIGHT=16>
            <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>
                <B><FONT style=FONT-SIZE:10pt FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000>Butterflied Hot Dog</FONT></B>
            </TD>
        </TR>
    </TABLE>
    <TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
        <TR HEIGHT=14>
            <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>
                <FONT style=FONT-SIZE:8pt FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000>all beef butterflied hot dog, grilled, American cheese, mustard, bacon, pickle spear, French </FONT>
            </TD>
        </TR>
    </TABLE>
    <TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
        <TR HEIGHT=12>
            <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>
                <FONT style=FONT-SIZE:8pt FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000>fries $6.50</FONT>
            </TD>
        </TR>
    </TABLE>
    <TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
        <TR HEIGHT=16>
            <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>
                <B><FONT style=FONT-SIZE:10pt FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000>Pulled BBQ Pork Sliders</FONT></B>
            </TD>
        </TR>
    </TABLE>
    <TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
        <TR HEIGHT=14>
            <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>
                <FONT style=FONT-SIZE:8pt FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000>Two tender smoked pulled pork sliders, barbeque sauce, Cheddar cheese, house made coleslaw, </FONT>
            </TD>
        </TR>
    </TABLE>
    <TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
        <TR HEIGHT=12>
            <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>
                <FONT style=FONT-SIZE:8pt FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000>French fries $8</FONT>
            </TD>
        </TR>
    </TABLE>
    <TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
        <TR HEIGHT=16>
            <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>
                <B><FONT style=FONT-SIZE:10pt FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000>Grilled Chicken Avocado Club Sandwich</FONT></B>
            </TD>
        </TR>
    </TABLE>
    <TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
        <TR HEIGHT=14>
            <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>
                <FONT style=FONT-SIZE:8pt FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000>Boneless chicken breast char-grilled, avocado, Swiss cheese, bacon, lettuce, tomato, mayonnaise, </FONT>
            </TD>
        </TR>
    </TABLE>
    <TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
        <TR HEIGHT=12>
            <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>
                <FONT style=FONT-SIZE:8pt FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000>house made macaroni salad $10.50</FONT>
            </TD>
        </TR>
    </TABLE>
    <TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
        <TR HEIGHT=19>
            <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>
                <B><FONT style=FONT-SIZE:12pt FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000>Desserts</FONT></B>
            </TD>
        </TR>
    </TABLE>
    <TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
        <TR HEIGHT=14>
            <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>
                <FONT style=FONT-SIZE:8pt FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000>Chocolate Oreo Cream Cake | Kentucky Bourbon Pecan Pie</FONT>
            </TD>
        </TR>
    </TABLE>
    <TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
        <TR HEIGHT=14>
            <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>
                <FONT style=FONT-SIZE:8pt FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000>Double Chocolate Peppermint Brownie w/ Mint Chocolate Chip Ice Cream &amp; Hot Fudge+</FONT>
            </TD>
        </TR>
    </TABLE>
    <TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
        <TR HEIGHT=14>
            <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>
                <FONT style=FONT-SIZE:8pt FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000>Brownie Bottom Sundae | Hot Fudge Cream Puff</FONT>
            </TD>
        </TR>
    </TABLE>
    <TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
        <TR HEIGHT=14>
            <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>
                <FONT style=FONT-SIZE:8pt FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000>Cr&egrave;me Brulee+ | Vanilla Cheesecake</FONT>
            </TD>
        </TR>
    </TABLE>
    <TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
        <TR HEIGHT=14>
            <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>
                <FONT style=FONT-SIZE:8pt FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000>Key Lime Pie | Coconut Macaroon w/ Sorbet++</FONT>
            </TD>
        </TR>
    </TABLE>
    <TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
        <TR HEIGHT=14>
            <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>
                <FONT style=FONT-SIZE:8pt FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000>+ Gluten Free ++ Gluten and Dairy Free</FONT>
            </TD>
        </TR>
    </TABLE>
    <TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
        <TR HEIGHT=16>
            <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>
                <B><FONT style=FONT-SIZE:10pt FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000>*</FONT></B>
            </TD>
        </TR>
    </TABLE>
    <TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
        <TR HEIGHT=14>
            <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>
                <FONT style=FONT-SIZE:8pt FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000>* These items are cooked to order and the consumption of raw or undercooked meats, fish or shellfish </FONT>
            </TD>
        </TR>
    </TABLE>
    <TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
        <TR HEIGHT=12>
            <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>
                <FONT style=FONT-SIZE:8pt FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000>may increase your risk of food borne illness.</FONT>
            </TD>
        </TR>
    </TABLE>
    <TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
        <TR HEIGHT=19>
            <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>
                <B><FONT style=FONT-SIZE:12pt FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000>Drink Specials</FONT></B>
            </TD>
        </TR>
    </TABLE>
    <TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
        <TR HEIGHT=16>
            <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>
                <B><FONT style=FONT-SIZE:10pt FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000>House Made SANGRIA $6 Glass |  $16 Carafe</FONT></B>
            </TD>
        </TR>
    </TABLE>
    <TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
        <TR HEIGHT=19>
            <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>
                <B><FONT style=FONT-SIZE:12pt FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000>Rotating Wine</FONT></B>
            </TD>
        </TR>
    </TABLE>
    <TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
        <TR HEIGHT=16>
            <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>
                <B><FONT style=FONT-SIZE:10pt FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000>The Prisoner Red Blend, Napa Valley, CA '15 | $66 Btl</FONT></B>
            </TD>
        </TR>
    </TABLE>
    <TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
        <TR HEIGHT=16>
            <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>
                <B><FONT style=FONT-SIZE:10pt FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000>Balletto Pinor Noir, Sonoma, '13 | 8 oz. $15 | Btl $46</FONT></B>
            </TD>
        </TR>
    </TABLE>
    <TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
        <TR HEIGHT=16>
            <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>
                <B><FONT style=FONT-SIZE:10pt FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000>Red Diamond Malbec, Mendoza-Argentina, '12 | 8 oz. $9 | Btl $28</FONT></B>
            </TD>
        </TR>
    </TABLE>
```

I have another part of this project that I have a form for and I have the values being stored via JSON. With that being said, I would like a way to be able to loop through the table and store the items into arrays and then combine the arrays into one JSON file at the end so that I can use that and compare elsewhere within this project. Here is the code I have for getting this HTML table file and then parsing it partially, but I am stuck in trying to figure out the loop. Here is that code:

```
$.get('/specials/lunch_klm.html', function(data) {
  var rows = jQuery($.parseHTML(data)).find("tr");
  var results = [];
  var category = [];
  var apps = [];
  var soups = [];
  var entrees = [];
  var desserts = [];
  rows.each(function(i) {
    thiz = jQuery(this);
    var markup = thiz.html();
    var text = $.trim(thiz.text());
    if( text == 'Soups') {
      results.push(text);
    }
  })
  console.log(soups);
}, 'html');
```

I would like to loop until I hit the text value Soups, then put the next few rows values into the soups array, until I get to "Lunch Selections", and then store just the titles of the entrees, not the descriptions. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You know that you don't have "an" HTML table? You have many, many tables. This can be done, but the effort to do it will far outweigh the effort to make the HTML modern. Tell your client that.

Comment: Like I stated, I am not looking to make this modern HTML table. I just need to parse it and store the data.

Comment: I understand. I'm just trying to tell you that the answer you seek is going to be so involved that you are unlikely to get an answer here. Why would you want to spend one hour writing convoluted code when you can take a half an hour to bring everything up to spec. and have a clear, clean answer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14591538/javascript-looping-through-all-cells-in-table
The chosen answer will loop through nested tables.

Comment: Considering that this is produced from a Windows Access table application, it is not so simple as to update it in 30 minutes. I would spend more time with it, than I would this, hence why I am trying to find a solution.

Comment: I concur with the other commenters - the only conceivable way to do what you're asking is a convoluted regex, that is entirely specific to this one, exact menu (if they add any of the heading word strings elsewhere, it immediately stops functioning). You could easily accomplish what you want with the single change of adding classes to the elements you wish to capture from the original tables, which is the clear solution.

Comment: Well, ok. That's why I'm posting a comment and not an answer. But, here's more insight for you. Access tables are not meant to serve as web back-ends. You will encounter table locked errors as soon as you have about 10 concurrent requests.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I totally get what you are saying and I agree with you, however, my client does not want to switch at this time. They have been doing it this way for years and have thousands of food items with descriptions stored in here.

Comment: I understand. You are just not going to get anyone here interested in helping you to patch a woefully out of date system.

Comment: I appreciate your comments anyways. If I find a solution without redoing their current application, I will post it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would get you started. It is difficult however to separate items from descriptions of items without some sort of classes added to the rows. I started filtering these descriptions by using an array of `ignoreText` which works on a few descriptions for now

If it was feasible to have classes added in back end it would greatly simplify problem

```js
// predefine the categories in array
// if needed could generate these by inspecting `font-size`
var cats = ['Soups', 'Lunch Selections', 'Desserts', 'Drink Specials','Rotating Wine'],
  ignoreText = ['*', 'may increase'],  
  currCat = null,
  // create object with cats as keys and empty arrays to push data to
  items = cats.reduce(function(a, c) {
    a[c] = [];
    return a;
  }, {});

// would be what you receive in your ajax, used helper function for demo
var ajaxData = get_data()

$(ajaxData).filter('table').each(function() {
  var txt = $(this).text().trim(),
    isCatHeading = cats.indexOf(txt) > -1;

  if (isCatHeading) {
    currCat = txt
  }

  if (currCat && !isCatHeading) {
    // see if start of txt is in the "ignore" array
    var isIgnoreText = ignoreText.filter(function(reg) {
      return txt.indexOf(reg) === 0;
    }).length;

    if (!isIgnoreText) {
      items[currCat].push(txt)
    }
  }
});
// display data in demo
$('pre').text(JSON.stringify(items, null, 4));

//helper function for demo
function get_data(){
  return `<TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
    <TR HEIGHT=16>
      <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>
        <B><FONT style=FONT-SIZE:10pt FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000>Chef's Selections for Tuesday, April 25, 2017</FONT></B>
      </TD>
    </TR>
  </TABLE>
  <TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
    <TR HEIGHT=14>
      <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>
        <B><FONT style=FONT-SIZE:8pt FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000>SPRING FLING! Please ask us about our Bell's Beer Pairing! May 22nd!</FONT></B>
      </TD>
    </TR>
  </TABLE>
  <TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
    <TR HEIGHT=19>
      <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>
        <B><FONT style=FONT-SIZE:12pt FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000>Soups</FONT></B>
      </TD>
    </TR>
  </TABLE>
  <TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
    <TR HEIGHT=14>
      <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>
        <FONT style=FONT-SIZE:8pt FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000>Beef Vegetable</FONT>
      </TD>
    </TR>
  </TABLE>
  <TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
    <TR HEIGHT=14>
      <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>
        <FONT style=FONT-SIZE:8pt FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000>Cream of Tomato</FONT>
      </TD>
    </TR>
  </TABLE>
  <TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
    <TR HEIGHT=19>
      <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>
        <B><FONT style=FONT-SIZE:12pt FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000>Lunch Selections</FONT></B>
      </TD>
    </TR>
  </TABLE>
  <TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
    <TR HEIGHT=16>
      <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>
        <B><FONT style=FONT-SIZE:10pt FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000>Butterflied Hot Dog</FONT></B>
      </TD>
    </TR>
  </TABLE>
  <TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
    <TR HEIGHT=14>
      <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>
        <FONT style=FONT-SIZE:8pt FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000>all beef butterflied hot dog, grilled, American cheese, mustard, bacon, pickle spear, French </FONT>
      </TD>
    </TR>
  </TABLE>
  <TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
    <TR HEIGHT=12>
      <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>
        <FONT style=FONT-SIZE:8pt FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000>fries $6.50</FONT>
      </TD>
    </TR>
  </TABLE>
  <TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
    <TR HEIGHT=16>
      <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>
        <B><FONT style=FONT-SIZE:10pt FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000>Pulled BBQ Pork Sliders</FONT></B>
      </TD>
    </TR>
  </TABLE>
  <TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
    <TR HEIGHT=14>
      <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>
        <FONT style=FONT-SIZE:8pt FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000>Two tender smoked pulled pork sliders, barbeque sauce, Cheddar cheese, house made coleslaw, </FONT>
      </TD>
    </TR>
  </TABLE>
  <TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
    <TR HEIGHT=12>
      <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>
        <FONT style=FONT-SIZE:8pt FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000>French fries $8</FONT>
      </TD>
    </TR>
  </TABLE>
  <TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
    <TR HEIGHT=16>
      <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>
        <B><FONT style=FONT-SIZE:10pt FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000>Grilled Chicken Avocado Club Sandwich</FONT></B>
      </TD>
    </TR>
  </TABLE>
  <TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
    <TR HEIGHT=14>
      <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>
        <FONT style=FONT-SIZE:8pt FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000>Boneless chicken breast char-grilled, avocado, Swiss cheese, bacon, lettuce, tomato, mayonnaise, </FONT>
      </TD>
    </TR>
  </TABLE>
  <TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
    <TR HEIGHT=12>
      <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>
        <FONT style=FONT-SIZE:8pt FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000>house made macaroni salad $10.50</FONT>
      </TD>
    </TR>
  </TABLE>
  <TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
    <TR HEIGHT=19>
      <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>
        <B><FONT style=FONT-SIZE:12pt FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000>Desserts</FONT></B>
      </TD>
    </TR>
  </TABLE>
  <TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
    <TR HEIGHT=14>
      <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>
        <FONT style=FONT-SIZE:8pt FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000>Chocolate Oreo Cream Cake | Kentucky Bourbon Pecan Pie</FONT>
      </TD>
    </TR>
  </TABLE>
  <TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
    <TR HEIGHT=14>
      <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>
        <FONT style=FONT-SIZE:8pt FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000>Double Chocolate Peppermint Brownie w/ Mint Chocolate Chip Ice Cream &amp; Hot Fudge+</FONT>
      </TD>
    </TR>
  </TABLE>
  <TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
    <TR HEIGHT=14>
      <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>
        <FONT style=FONT-SIZE:8pt FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000>Brownie Bottom Sundae | Hot Fudge Cream Puff</FONT>
      </TD>
    </TR>
  </TABLE>
  <TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
    <TR HEIGHT=14>
      <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>
        <FONT style=FONT-SIZE:8pt FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000>Cr&egrave;me Brulee+ | Vanilla Cheesecake</FONT>
      </TD>
    </TR>
  </TABLE>
  <TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
    <TR HEIGHT=14>
      <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>
        <FONT style=FONT-SIZE:8pt FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000>Key Lime Pie | Coconut Macaroon w/ Sorbet++</FONT>
      </TD>
    </TR>
  </TABLE>
  <TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
    <TR HEIGHT=14>
      <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>
        <FONT style=FONT-SIZE:8pt FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000>+ Gluten Free ++ Gluten and Dairy Free</FONT>
      </TD>
    </TR>
  </TABLE>
  <TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
    <TR HEIGHT=16>
      <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>
        <B><FONT style=FONT-SIZE:10pt FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000>*</FONT></B>
      </TD>
    </TR>
  </TABLE>
  <TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
    <TR HEIGHT=14>
      <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>
        <FONT style=FONT-SIZE:8pt FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000>* These items are cooked to order and the consumption of raw or undercooked meats, fish or shellfish </FONT>
      </TD>
    </TR>
  </TABLE>
  <TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
    <TR HEIGHT=12>
      <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>
        <FONT style=FONT-SIZE:8pt FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000>may increase your risk of food borne illness.</FONT>
      </TD>
    </TR>
  </TABLE>
  <TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
    <TR HEIGHT=19>
      <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>
        <B><FONT style=FONT-SIZE:12pt FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000>Drink Specials</FONT></B>
      </TD>
    </TR>
  </TABLE>
  <TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
    <TR HEIGHT=16>
      <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>
        <B><FONT style=FONT-SIZE:10pt FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000>House Made SANGRIA $6 Glass |  $16 Carafe</FONT></B>
      </TD>
    </TR>
  </TABLE>
  <TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
    <TR HEIGHT=19>
      <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>
        <B><FONT style=FONT-SIZE:12pt FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000>Rotating Wine</FONT></B>
      </TD>
    </TR>
  </TABLE>
  <TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
    <TR HEIGHT=16>
      <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>
        <B><FONT style=FONT-SIZE:10pt FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000>The Prisoner Red Blend, Napa Valley, CA '15 | $66 Btl</FONT></B>
      </TD>
    </TR>
  </TABLE>
  <TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
    <TR HEIGHT=16>
      <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>
        <B><FONT style=FONT-SIZE:10pt FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000>Balletto Pinor Noir, Sonoma, '13 | 8 oz. $15 | Btl $46</FONT></B>
      </TD>
    </TR>
  </TABLE>
  <TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
    <TR HEIGHT=16>
      <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>
        <B><FONT style=FONT-SIZE:10pt FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000>Red Diamond Malbec, Mendoza-Argentina, '12 | 8 oz. $9 | Btl $28</FONT></B>
      </TD>
    </TR>
  </TABLE>`

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>
Data
</h4>
<pre>Test</pre>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I will look into how I can implement this and separate out the descriptions. I appreciate your help.

Comment: I just tested this out and it gets me closer to what I want and gives me the ability to work with it and fine tune it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

`table` contains `rows[]`, which themselves contain `cells[]`. You can't get the `cells[]` directly from the `table`.

You could use `table.getElementsByTagName('td')` as a shortcut, provided there are no nested tables.

Otherwise, you should loop through each of the `rows[]` and in that loop you can loop through the `cells[]`.

```js
var tables = document.getElementsByTagName('table'),
  i;
for (i = 0; i < tables.length; i++) {
  var table = tables[i],
    rows = table.rows,
    rowcount = rows.length,
    r,
    cells, cellcount, c, cell;
  for (r = 0; r < rowcount; r++) {
    cells = rows[r].cells;
    cellcount = cells.length;
    for (c = 0; c < cellcount; c++) {
      cell = cells[c];
      console.log(cell.textContent);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
  <TR HEIGHT=16>
    <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>
      <B><FONT style=FONT-SIZE:10pt FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000>Chef's Selections for Tuesday, April 25, 2017</FONT></B>
    </TD>
  </TR>
</TABLE>
<TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
  <TR HEIGHT=14>
    <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>
      <B><FONT style=FONT-SIZE:8pt FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000>SPRING FLING! Please ask us about our Bell's Beer Pairing! May 22nd!</FONT></B>
    </TD>
  </TR>
</TABLE>
<TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
  <TR HEIGHT=19>
    <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>
      <B><FONT style=FONT-SIZE:12pt FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000>Soups</FONT></B>
    </TD>
  </TR>
</TABLE>
<TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
  <TR HEIGHT=14>
    <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>
      <FONT style=FONT-SIZE:8pt FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000>Beef Vegetable</FONT>
    </TD>
  </TR>
</TABLE>
<TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
  <TR HEIGHT=14>
    <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>
      <FONT style=FONT-SIZE:8pt FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000>Cream of Tomato</FONT>
    </TD>
  </TR>
</TABLE>
<TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
  <TR HEIGHT=19>
    <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>
      <B><FONT style=FONT-SIZE:12pt FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000>Lunch Selections</FONT></B>
    </TD>
  </TR>
</TABLE>
<TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
  <TR HEIGHT=16>
    <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>
      <B><FONT style=FONT-SIZE:10pt FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000>Butterflied Hot Dog</FONT></B>
    </TD>
  </TR>
</TABLE>
<TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
  <TR HEIGHT=14>
    <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>
      <FONT style=FONT-SIZE:8pt FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000>all beef butterflied hot dog, grilled, American cheese, mustard, bacon, pickle spear, French </FONT>
    </TD>
  </TR>
</TABLE>
<TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
  <TR HEIGHT=12>
    <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>
      <FONT style=FONT-SIZE:8pt FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000>fries $6.50</FONT>
    </TD>
  </TR>
</TABLE>
<TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
  <TR HEIGHT=16>
    <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>
      <B><FONT style=FONT-SIZE:10pt FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000>Pulled BBQ Pork Sliders</FONT></B>
    </TD>
  </TR>
</TABLE>
<TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
  <TR HEIGHT=14>
    <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>
      <FONT style=FONT-SIZE:8pt FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000>Two tender smoked pulled pork sliders, barbeque sauce, Cheddar cheese, house made coleslaw, </FONT>
    </TD>
  </TR>
</TABLE>
<TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
  <TR HEIGHT=12>
    <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>
      <FONT style=FONT-SIZE:8pt FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000>French fries $8</FONT>
    </TD>
  </TR>
</TABLE>
<TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
  <TR HEIGHT=16>
    <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>
      <B><FONT style=FONT-SIZE:10pt FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000>Grilled Chicken Avocado Club Sandwich</FONT></B>
    </TD>
  </TR>
</TABLE>
<TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
  <TR HEIGHT=14>
    <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>
      <FONT style=FONT-SIZE:8pt FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000>Boneless chicken breast char-grilled, avocado, Swiss cheese, bacon, lettuce, tomato, mayonnaise, </FONT>
    </TD>
  </TR>
</TABLE>
<TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
  <TR HEIGHT=12>
    <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>
      <FONT style=FONT-SIZE:8pt FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000>house made macaroni salad $10.50</FONT>
    </TD>
  </TR>
</TABLE>
<TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
  <TR HEIGHT=19>
    <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>
      <B><FONT style=FONT-SIZE:12pt FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000>Desserts</FONT></B>
    </TD>
  </TR>
</TABLE>
<TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
  <TR HEIGHT=14>
    <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>
      <FONT style=FONT-SIZE:8pt FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000>Chocolate Oreo Cream Cake | Kentucky Bourbon Pecan Pie</FONT>
    </TD>
  </TR>
</TABLE>
<TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
  <TR HEIGHT=14>
    <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>
      <FONT style=FONT-SIZE:8pt FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000>Double Chocolate Peppermint Brownie w/ Mint Chocolate Chip Ice Cream &amp; Hot Fudge+</FONT>
    </TD>
  </TR>
</TABLE>
<TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
  <TR HEIGHT=14>
    <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>
      <FONT style=FONT-SIZE:8pt FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000>Brownie Bottom Sundae | Hot Fudge Cream Puff</FONT>
    </TD>
  </TR>
</TABLE>
<TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
  <TR HEIGHT=14>
    <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>
      <FONT style=FONT-SIZE:8pt FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000>Cr&egrave;me Brulee+ | Vanilla Cheesecake</FONT>
    </TD>
  </TR>
</TABLE>
<TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
  <TR HEIGHT=14>
    <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>
      <FONT style=FONT-SIZE:8pt FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000>Key Lime Pie | Coconut Macaroon w/ Sorbet++</FONT>
    </TD>
  </TR>
</TABLE>
<TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
  <TR HEIGHT=14>
    <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>
      <FONT style=FONT-SIZE:8pt FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000>+ Gluten Free ++ Gluten and Dairy Free</FONT>
    </TD>
  </TR>
</TABLE>
<TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
  <TR HEIGHT=16>
    <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>
      <B><FONT style=FONT-SIZE:10pt FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000>*</FONT></B>
    </TD>
  </TR>
</TABLE>
<TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
  <TR HEIGHT=14>
    <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>
      <FONT style=FONT-SIZE:8pt FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000>* These items are cooked to order and the consumption of raw or undercooked meats, fish or shellfish </FONT>
    </TD>
  </TR>
</TABLE>
<TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
  <TR HEIGHT=12>
    <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>
      <FONT style=FONT-SIZE:8pt FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000>may increase your risk of food borne illness.</FONT>
    </TD>
  </TR>
</TABLE>
<TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
  <TR HEIGHT=19>
    <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>
      <B><FONT style=FONT-SIZE:12pt FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000>Drink Specials</FONT></B>
    </TD>
  </TR>
</TABLE>
<TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
  <TR HEIGHT=16>
    <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>
      <B><FONT style=FONT-SIZE:10pt FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000>House Made SANGRIA $6 Glass |  $16 Carafe</FONT></B>
    </TD>
  </TR>
</TABLE>
<TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
  <TR HEIGHT=19>
    <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>
      <B><FONT style=FONT-SIZE:12pt FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000>Rotating Wine</FONT></B>
    </TD>
  </TR>
</TABLE>
<TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
  <TR HEIGHT=16>
    <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>
      <B><FONT style=FONT-SIZE:10pt FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000>The Prisoner Red Blend, Napa Valley, CA '15 | $66 Btl</FONT></B>
    </TD>
  </TR>
</TABLE>
<TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
  <TR HEIGHT=16>
    <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>
      <B><FONT style=FONT-SIZE:10pt FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000>Balletto Pinor Noir, Sonoma, '13 | 8 oz. $15 | Btl $46</FONT></B>
    </TD>
  </TR>
</TABLE>
<TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
  <TR HEIGHT=16>
    <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>
      <B><FONT style=FONT-SIZE:10pt FACE="Arial" COLOR=#000000>Red Diamond Malbec, Mendoza-Argentina, '12 | 8 oz. $9 | Btl $28</FONT></B>
    </TD>
  </TR>
</TABLE>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would probably need a piece of logic like this:

```
var str = "<TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0><TR HEIGHT=16>            <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF><B><FONT style=FONT-SIZE:10pt FACE=\"Arial\" COLOR=#000000>Chef's Selections for Tuesday, April 25, 2017</FONT></B></TD> </TR></TABLE><TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0><TR HEIGHT=16>            <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF><B><FONT style=FONT-SIZE:10pt FACE=\"Arial\" COLOR=#000000>SPRING FLING! Please ask us about our Bell's Beer Pairing! May 22nd!</FONT></B></TD> </TR></TABLE><TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0><TR HEIGHT=16>            <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF><B><FONT style=FONT-SIZE:10pt FACE=\"Arial\" COLOR=#000000>Soups</FONT></B></TD> </TR></TABLE><TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0><TR HEIGHT=16>            <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF><B><FONT style=FONT-SIZE:10pt FACE=\"Arial\" COLOR=#000000>Beef Vegetable</FONT></B></TD> </TR></TABLE><TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0><TR HEIGHT=16>            <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF><B><FONT style=FONT-SIZE:10pt FACE=\"Arial\" COLOR=#000000>Cream of Tomato</FONT></B></TD> </TR></TABLE><TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0><TR HEIGHT=16>            <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF><B><FONT style=FONT-SIZE:10pt FACE=\"Arial\" COLOR=#000000>Lunch Selections</FONT></B></TD> </TR></TABLE><TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0><TR HEIGHT=16>            <TD WIDTH=456 ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF><B><FONT style=FONT-SIZE:10pt FACE=\"Arial\" COLOR=#000000>Butterflied Hot Dog</FONT></B></TD> </TR></TABLE>",
  html = $.parseHTML( str ),
  results = [],
  soups = [],
  entrees = [];

var currentArr = results;

$.each( html, function( i, el ) {
  var t = $(el).find("font").text();

  if ("Soups" == t) {
    results.push("<li>" + t + "</li>");
    currentArr = soups;
  }
  else if ("Lunch Selections" == t) {
    results.push("<li>" + t + "</li>");
    currentArr = entrees;
  }
  // you may need another if condition here to switch currentArr back to results
  else {
    currentArr.push("<li>" + t + "</li>");
  }

});
```

Please refer to [this](https://jsfiddle.net/zdhuzbzz/) to see how it runs in action. Hope that can help.