# How to color table rows on the basis of column 'value' or 'text' in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am having column name as 'Status'. If status is 'Pass' i need to show that row  in green color. If 'fail' then red. How to do it in javascript?

```
for (i=0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var value = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
    if (value == 'Pass') {
        rows[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
}
```

I tried this but it is not supported by browser. Kindly help. Thanks.

Comment: Would you like to use jQuery?

Comment: i tried $('.status:contains("Pass")').css('color', 'green');
$('.status:contains("Fail")').css('color', 'red'); this

Comment: Where does `rows` come from? What particular part isn't supported by your browser, and which browser are you using?

Comment: can you try adding the custom css class to the row, by defining a css class

Comment: Can you show us the table markup also

Comment: or else you can try this...

$(this).css('background-color', '#CC3333');

Comment: function CheckStatus(id)
{
 var table = document.getElementById(id);
 
 var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

Comment: Have a look at this this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3065342/how-do-i-iterate-through-table-rows-and-cells-in-javascript

Comment: Kindly suggest on the same. Given answers are not working

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery you can try:

```
function CheckStatus(id) {
    var rows = $('#'+id).find("tr")
    $(rows).each(function(){
        var value =  $(this).find('td:first').text();
        if (value == 'Pass') {
            $(this).css('background', 'red');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: jquery? where in the question?

Comment: OP already tried. $('.status:contains("Pass")').css('color', 'green'); $('.status:contains("Fail")').css('color', 'red');

Comment: on principle as I say jquery is not the anser to everything

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i=0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var value = document.getElementsByTagName("td")[i].firstChild.nodeValue;
    if (value == 'Pass') {
        document.getElementsByTagName("td")[i].style.backgroundColor = "green";
    }
else{ document.getElementsByTagName("td")[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";}
}
```

try this code (I didn't try yet though, thiss the idea what you need)

Answer (score 0):

I would use class names instead of setting the style but try this:

```
for (i=0; i < rows.length; i++) { 
   var value =  = rows[i].cells[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
   if (value == 'Pass') {
        rows[i].className = "red";
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Styles can only be implemented on HTML elements e.g. text box, select, text etc. In your case you are trying to style a value of 'rows', which is not correct. You need to select the HTML element and then style it.

Something like this might help:

```
for (i=0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var value = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
    if (value == 'Pass') {
        rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0].firstChild.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can try using the Jquery

```
   $(document).ready(function () { 
            $("#testResults tr").each(function () { 
                var row = $(this).find("td:nth-child(2)").text(); 
                if (row == 'Pass') { 
                    $(this).css('background-color', '#F00'); 
                } else { 
                    $(this).css({ 'background-color': '#0G0',}); 
                } 
            }); 
        });
```

Comment: jquery is the answer to everything - although not in this case!