# populate dynamic table get value of td in a tr

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
var rowCount = $('.destination tr').length;
        for(var i = 1; i > rowCount; i++){
            alert(i);
            var continent = $('.destination').find('tr:nth-child('+i+')').find('td:nth-child(1)').text();
            var country = $('.destination').find('tr:nth-child('+ i +')').find('td:nth-child(2)').text();
            var city = $('.destination').find('tr:nth-child('+ i +')').find('td:nth-child(3)').text();

            //alert(rowCount[i]);

        }
```

This is from a code of my table i want to get the value of each td in each row like this but it is returning nothing it is not alerting `i` is something wrong here.any idea is a appreciated

Comment: You need to provide the HTML in your question

Comment: `rowCount` is an int, so what value are you expecting `rowCount[i]` to show? What output are you aiming for here, I'm guessing an array or an object?

Comment: Condition should be `i <= rowCount` instead of  `i > rowCount` and I would suggest you to use `$.each()`

Comment: the number of now where the td are located @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: it is returning even the header what i want is when i click the row only that row will return @Satpal

Comment: make a http://jsFiddle.net

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3065342/how-do-i-iterate-through-table-rows-and-cells-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `for` loop is checking for `"while greater than rowCount"` so it never fires even once!

That should have been:

```
for(var i = 1; <= rowCount; i++)
```

or better yet use 0-based indexing:

```
for(var i = 0; < rowCount; i++)
```

As you just want to iterate the rows and get the first 3 TDs, forget all the `nth-child` selectors and do it this much simpler way:

```
 var $rows = $('.destination tr');
 $rows.each(function(){
     var $tds = $(this).find('td');
     var continent = $td.eq(0).text();
     var country = $td.eq(1).text();
     var city = $td.eq(2).text();
     // Do something with the values
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's faster and more comfortable to access table rows and cells without jQuery:

```
var table = ...;
for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
   for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
   }
}
```

The assignment in the condition of the loop makes it stop when the index runs out of rows/cells.

See: [How do I iterate through table rows and cells in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3065342/how-do-i-iterate-through-table-rows-and-cells-in-javascript)