# for loop inconsistency in table rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```js
//Iterate through stuff with for loop method
//http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3065342/how-do-i-iterate-through-table-rows-and-cells-in-javascript
var omitTD = $('.ColHead').closest('tr').find('td:eq(0), td:eq(1)'), headerTD = $('.ColHead').closest('tr').find('td').not(omitTD);
  ;
var table = document.getElementById("mytab1");
for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
  for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
    headerTD.eq(j).css("background-color", "#ACE");
  }
}
headerTD.text('Target This');
omitTD.text('Dont Target');
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td,
tr {
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="mytab1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2"></td>
      <td class="mrGridQuestionText" style=""></td>
      <td colspan="3" class="mrGridQuestionText" style="">
        <div class="ColHead"></div>
        <center>
          <span class="mrQuestionText" style=""><div class="ColHead"></div>Carrier
                                
                        <br>
            Selection/
                                
                            <br>
            Negotiation
                            
                            </span>
        </center>
      </td>
      <td colspan="3" class="mrGridQuestionText" style="">
        <center>
          <span class="mrQuestionText" style="">Order
                                
                                <br>
            Fulfillment
                            
                                </span>
        </center>
      </td>
      <td colspan="3" class="mrGridQuestionText" style="">
        <center>
          <span class="mrQuestionText" style="">Transportation
                                
                                    <br>
            Distribution
                            
                                    </span>
        </center>
      </td>
      <td colspan="3" class="mrGridQuestionText" style="">
        <center>
          <span class="mrQuestionText" style="">Inventory
                                
                                        <br>
            Management
                            
                                        </span>
        </center>
      </td>
      <td colspan="3" class="mrGridQuestionText" style="">
        <center>
          <span class="mrQuestionText" style="">Logistics
                                
                                            <br>
            Information
                                
                                                <br>
            Systems
                            
                                                </span>
        </center>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="mrGridQuestionText" style="text-Align: Center;vertical-align: Bottom;width: 40px;border-color: black;border-style: Solid;border-width: 1px;">
        <span class="mrQuestionText" style="font-size: 9pt;">Have Used</span>
      </td>
      <td class="mrGridQuestionText" style="text-Align: Center;vertical-align: Bottom;width: 40px;border-color: black;border-style: Solid;border-width: 1px;">
        <span class="mrQuestionText" style="font-size: 9pt;">A</span>
      </td>
      <td class="mrGridQuestionText" style="text-Align: Center;vertical-align: Bottom;width: 40px;border-color: black;border-style: Solid;border-width: 1px;">
        <span class="mrQuestionText" style="font-size: 9pt;">B</span>
      </td>
      <td class="mrGridQuestionText" style="text-Align: Center;vertical-align: Bottom;width: 40px;border-color: black;border-style: Solid;border-width: 1px;">
        <span class="mrQuestionText" style="font-size: 9pt;">C</span>
      </td>
      <td class="mrGridQuestionText" style="text-Align: Center;vertical-align: Bottom;width: 40px;border-color: black;border-style: Solid;border-width: 1px;">
        <span class="mrQuestionText" style="font-size: 9pt;">A</span>
      </td>
      <td class="mrGridQuestionText" style="text-Align: Center;vertical-align: Bottom;width: 40px;border-color: black;border-style: Solid;border-width: 1px;">
        <span class="mrQuestionText" style="font-size: 9pt;">B</span>
      </td>
      <td class="mrGridQuestionText" style="text-Align: Center;vertical-align: Bottom;width: 40px;border-color: black;border-style: Solid;border-width: 1px;">
        <span class="mrQuestionText" style="font-size: 9pt;">C</span>
      </td>
      <td class="mrGridQuestionText" style="text-Align: Center;vertical-align: Bottom;width: 40px;border-color: black;border-style: Solid;border-width: 1px;">
        <span class="mrQuestionText" style="font-size: 9pt;">A</span>
      </td>
      <td class="mrGridQuestionText" style="text-Align: Center;vertical-align: Bottom;width: 40px;border-color: black;border-style: Solid;border-width: 1px;">
        <span class="mrQuestionText" style="font-size: 9pt;">B</span>
      </td>
      <td class="mrGridQuestionText" style="text-Align: Center;vertical-align: Bottom;width: 40px;border-color: black;border-style: Solid;border-width: 1px;">
        <span class="mrQuestionText" style="font-size: 9pt;">C</span>
      </td>
      <td class="mrGridQuestionText" style="text-Align: Center;vertical-align: Bottom;width: 40px;border-color: black;border-style: Solid;border-width: 1px;">
        <span class="mrQuestionText" style="font-size: 9pt;">A</span>
      </td>
      <td class="mrGridQuestionText" style="text-Align: Center;vertical-align: Bottom;width: 40px;border-color: black;border-style: Solid;border-width: 1px;">
        <span class="mrQuestionText" style="font-size: 9pt;">B</span>
      </td>
      <td class="mrGridQuestionText" style="text-Align: Center;vertical-align: Bottom;width: 40px;border-color: black;border-style: Solid;border-width: 1px;">
        <span class="mrQuestionText" style="font-size: 9pt;">C</span>
      </td>
      <td class="mrGridQuestionText" style="text-Align: Center;vertical-align: Bottom;width: 40px;border-color: black;border-style: Solid;border-width: 1px;">
        <span class="mrQuestionText" style="font-size: 9pt;">A</span>
      </td>
      <td class="mrGridQuestionText" style="text-Align: Center;vertical-align: Bottom;width: 40px;border-color: black;border-style: Solid;border-width: 1px;">
        <span class="mrQuestionText" style="font-size: 9pt;">B</span>
      </td>
      <td class="mrGridQuestionText" style="text-Align: Center;vertical-align: Bottom;width: 40px;border-color: black;border-style: Solid;border-width: 1px;">
        <span class="mrQuestionText" style="font-size: 9pt;">C</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2"></td>
      <td class="mrGridQuestionText" style=""></td>
      <td colspan="3" class="mrGridQuestionText" style="">
        <div class="ColHead"></div>
        <center>
          <span class="mrQuestionText" style=""><div class="ColHead"></div>Carrier
                                
                                                    <br>
            Selection/
                                
                                                        <br>
            Negotiation
                            
                                                        </span>
        </center>
      </td>
      <td colspan="3" class="mrGridQuestionText" style="">
        <center>
          <span class="mrQuestionText" style="">Order
                                
                                                            <br>
            Fulfillment
                            
                                                            </span>
        </center>
      </td>
      <td colspan="3" class="mrGridQuestionText" style="">
        <center>
          <span class="mrQuestionText" style="">Transportation
                                
                                                                <br>
            Distribution
                            
                                                                </span>
        </center>
      </td>
      <td colspan="3" class="mrGridQuestionText" style="">
        <center>
          <span class="mrQuestionText" style="">Inventory
                                
                                                                    <br>
            Management
                            
                                                                    </span>
        </center>
      </td>
      <td colspan="3" class="mrGridQuestionText" style="">
        <center>
          <span class="mrQuestionText" style="">Logistics
                                
                                                                        <br>
            Information
                                
                                                                            <br>
            Systems
                            
                                                                            </span>
        </center>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="mrGridQuestionText" style="text-Align: Center;vertical-align: Bottom;width: 40px;border-color: black;border-style: Solid;border-width: 1px;">
        <span class="mrQuestionText" style="font-size: 9pt;">Have Used</span>
      </td>
      <td class="mrGridQuestionText" style="text-Align: Center;vertical-align: Bottom;width: 40px;border-color: black;border-style: Solid;border-width: 1px;">
        <span class="mrQuestionText" style="font-size: 9pt;">A</span>
      </td>
      <td class="mrGridQuestionText" style="text-Align: Center;vertical-align: Bottom;width: 40px;border-color: black;border-style: Solid;border-width: 1px;">
        <span class="mrQuestionText" style="font-size: 9pt;">B</span>
      </td>
      <td class="mrGridQuestionText" style="text-Align: Center;vertical-align: Bottom;width: 40px;border-color: black;border-style: Solid;border-width: 1px;">
        <span class="mrQuestionText" style="font-size: 9pt;">C</span>
      </td>
      <td class="mrGridQuestionText" style="text-Align: Center;vertical-align: Bottom;width: 40px;border-color: black;border-style: Solid;border-width: 1px;">
        <span class="mrQuestionText" style="font-size: 9pt;">A</span>
      </td>
      <td class="mrGridQuestionText" style="text-Align: Center;vertical-align: Bottom;width: 40px;border-color: black;border-style: Solid;border-width: 1px;">
        <span class="mrQuestionText" style="font-size: 9pt;">B</span>
      </td>
      <td class="mrGridQuestionText" style="text-Align: Center;vertical-align: Bottom;width: 40px;border-color: black;border-style: Solid;border-width: 1px;">
        <span class="mrQuestionText" style="font-size: 9pt;">C</span>
      </td>
      <td class="mrGridQuestionText" style="text-Align: Center;vertical-align: Bottom;width: 40px;border-color: black;border-style: Solid;border-width: 1px;">
        <span class="mrQuestionText" style="font-size: 9pt;">A</span>
      </td>
      <td class="mrGridQuestionText" style="text-Align: Center;vertical-align: Bottom;width: 40px;border-color: black;border-style: Solid;border-width: 1px;">
        <span class="mrQuestionText" style="font-size: 9pt;">B</span>
      </td>
      <td class="mrGridQuestionText" style="text-Align: Center;vertical-align: Bottom;width: 40px;border-color: black;border-style: Solid;border-width: 1px;">
        <span class="mrQuestionText" style="font-size: 9pt;">C</span>
      </td>
      <td class="mrGridQuestionText" style="text-Align: Center;vertical-align: Bottom;width: 40px;border-color: black;border-style: Solid;border-width: 1px;">
        <span class="mrQuestionText" style="font-size: 9pt;">A</span>
      </td>
      <td class="mrGridQuestionText" style="text-Align: Center;vertical-align: Bottom;width: 40px;border-color: black;border-style: Solid;border-width: 1px;">
        <span class="mrQuestionText" style="font-size: 9pt;">B</span>
      </td>
      <td class="mrGridQuestionText" style="text-Align: Center;vertical-align: Bottom;width: 40px;border-color: black;border-style: Solid;border-width: 1px;">
        <span class="mrQuestionText" style="font-size: 9pt;">C</span>
      </td>
      <td class="mrGridQuestionText" style="text-Align: Center;vertical-align: Bottom;width: 40px;border-color: black;border-style: Solid;border-width: 1px;">
        <span class="mrQuestionText" style="font-size: 9pt;">A</span>
      </td>
      <td class="mrGridQuestionText" style="text-Align: Center;vertical-align: Bottom;width: 40px;border-color: black;border-style: Solid;border-width: 1px;">
        <span class="mrQuestionText" style="font-size: 9pt;">B</span>
      </td>
      <td class="mrGridQuestionText" style="text-Align: Center;vertical-align: Bottom;width: 40px;border-color: black;border-style: Solid;border-width: 1px;">
        <span class="mrQuestionText" style="font-size: 9pt;">C</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Why does the JavaScript code in the snippet work, but not the following:

```
//Iterate through stuff with for loop method
//http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3065342/how-do-i-iterate-through-table-rows-and-cells-in-javascript
var headerTD = $('.ColHead').closest('tr').find('td').not('td:eq(0), td:eq(1)'),
  omitTD = $('.ColHead').closest('tr').find('td:eq(0), td:eq(1)');
var table = document.getElementById("mytab1");
for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
  for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
    headerTD.eq(j).css("background-color", "#ACE");
  }
}
headerTD.text('Target This');
omitTD.text('Dont Target');
```

The goal is simply to apply some css to certain cells and exclude the first two, using a for loop.  Please note that I am deliberately not using the `.each()` which is much shorter code but slightly slower performance wise.

Comment: each() will not be user slower, there's no reason to make code more complex than needed... just dupe the class style with `:nth-child` selectors and not use js at all...

Comment: Since your `headerTD` code has two fewer elements in it, but your column loop still starts at zero, that `.eq(j)` test will mess things up. Using `.eq(j-2)` might help.

Comment: or start at 2 instead of zero and skip the extra method calls...

Comment: your for loop have no breaks!! when supposed it must break? by an Exception?

Comment: @dandavis starting at 2 produces the same error. Go on, test yourself in this sandbox... http://jsfiddle.net/dixalex/bbp8e0zx/2/

Comment: `row = table.rows[i]` are you trying to write == in both conditions?

Comment: @Sachin I don't really know what that does.  I got it from the link that is commented out in the script.  My goal there was to force iterate through all rows, in case it was being skipped.  For whatever reason, after the first row has been iterated, the exclusive parameter is dropped/ignored.  I'm trying to solve and figure out why that is.  I appreciate the insight thus far.

Comment: @jherax: the for loop will terminate when the middle segment is falsy, in this case, when there are no more cells =< to the index in the collection.

Comment: @AlexanderDixon: do you just want to hit all the header cells in the table, except ones that happen to be first or second in their row?

Comment: @dandavis Yes that is exactly it. And this is what is acheived in the snippet using the `not()` method.  I want to know, for future reference, why the code above not **not** work, and then a best practice approach using loops only.  The issue has nothing to do with CSS or nth-child selectors.  I chose this basic CSS task so that I could later apply it to something more complex.

Comment: ok, is the green on http://jsfiddle.net/now2rj1u/ in the right place? if so, i can help you convert the css to a loop...

Comment: @Pointy your response was the closest to understanding the core issue, however your suggestion did not work.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100193/discussion-between-alexander-dixon-and-dandavis).

Comment: @dandavis Yes that is correct.

Comment: the easy way: http://jsfiddle.net/now2rj1u/2/

Answer (score 0):

The code is not sooo clear to understand, but it appears that you want to set the background colour of the cells in the first table row, skipping the first two columns, yes?

If that's so, then you can just use CSS.

```
tr:first-of-type td:nth-child(n+3) {
  background-color: #ace;
}
```

If that first row is actually a heading row, then using a `<thead>` and `<th>` will make the CSS and the HTML a bit clearer:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>foo</th>
      <th>bar</th>
      <th>baz</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody> ...etc </tbody>
</table>


th:nth-child(n+3) {
  background-color: #ace;
}
```