# Loop through elements in a HTML table

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, loops, dom

I am learning Javascript, in a school assignment we have to by using a loop count how many games was made in 2014.

It does not return anything in the console, where have I gone wrong?

```js
var allGames = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
var array = Array.prototype.slice.call(allGames, 0)
var games14 = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
  if (array[i] == 2014) {
    games14++;
    console.log(games14)
  }
}
```

```html
<table id="games">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Titel</th>
      <th>Genre</th>
      <th>Årstal</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="games_tbody">
    <tr class="horror">
      <td class="title">Outlast</td>
      <td>Horror</td>
      <td>2013</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="rpg">
      <td class="title">Dragon Age: Inquisition</td>
      <td>Role-playing Game</td>
      <td>2014</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="rpg">
      <td class="title">Skyrim</td>
      <td>Role-playing Game</td>
      <td>2011</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="horror">
      <td class="title">Amnesia: The Dark Descent</td>
      <td>Horror</td>
      <td>2010</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="simulator">
      <td class="title">Scania Truck Driving Simulator</td>
      <td>Simulator</td>
      <td>2012</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="horror">
      <td class="title">Five Nights at Freddy’s</td>
      <td>Horror</td>
      <td>2014</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="simulator">
      <td class="title">Sims 4</td>
      <td>Simulator</td>
      <td>2014</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="rts" id="last">
      <td class="title">Warcraft III: Reign of Chaos</td>
      <td>Real-time Strategy</td>
      <td>2002</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You have to go through each row and column. Possible ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3065342/how-do-i-iterate-through-table-rows-and-cells-in-javascript

Comment: `if (array[i].textContent == '2014') {`

Answer (score 6):

You need to check for its text:

```
var allGames = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
...
 if (array[i].innerHTML == '2014') {
```

OR,

```
if(array[i].innerText == '2014' || array[i].textContent == '2014'){
```

Comment: Glad to help you ;)

Comment: @BhojendraNepal — I did not mean that.. `getElementsByTagName` returns an `HTMLCollection`, not `Element`.. Also note that `innerText` is [__Non-standard__](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText), you should be using [___`textContent`___](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) instead..

Comment: No need to do loop through elements in a HTML table.. Check my answer with [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Comment: @YosvelQuintero I agree with you but I'm just answering strictly to the OP Code.

Answer (score 3):

No need to do Loop through elements in a HTML table.. You can simply use [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) to count all occurrences within the `games_tbody`:

```js
var games14 = document
  .getElementById('games_tbody')
  .innerText
  .match(/2014/g)
  .length;

console.log('Games made in 2014:', games14);
```

```html
<table id="games">
  <thead>
    <tr><th>Titel</th><th>Genre</th><th>Årstal</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="games_tbody">
    <tr class="horror"><td class="title">Outlast</td><td>Horror</td><td>2013</td></tr>
    <tr class="rpg"><td class="title">Dragon Age: Inquisition</td><td>Role-playing Game</td><td>2014</td></tr>
    <tr class="rpg"><td class="title">Skyrim</td><td>Role-playing Game</td><td>2011</td></tr>
    <tr class="horror"><td class="title">Amnesia: The Dark Descent</td><td>Horror</td><td>2010</td></tr>
    <tr class="simulator"><td class="title">Scania Truck Driving Simulator</td><td>Simulator</td><td>2012</td></tr>
    <tr class="horror"><td class="title">Five Nights at Freddy’s</td><td>Horror</td><td>2014</td></tr>
    <tr class="simulator"><td class="title">Sims 4</td><td>Simulator</td><td>2014</td></tr>
    <tr class="rts" id="last"><td class="title">Warcraft III: Reign of Chaos</td><td>Real-time Strategy</td><td>2002</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> array[i] == 2014
> ```

Everything in the array will be an HTML Table Data Cell Element object.

Nothing in the array will be the Number 2014.

You need to read the text content from the element and then compare that.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a better way.

```
var table = document.getElementById("games");
count = 0;
for (let i = 0; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
    if (row.cells[2].innerHTML === "2014"){
        count++;
    }
/*
    for (let j = 0; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
        if (col.innerHTML === "2014"){
            count++;
        }
    }
*/ 
}
console.log(count);
```

The commented code is for checking every item on a single row.