# Bootstrap table - dynamic button in row

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, html-table

I am using *bootstrap v3*. I try to get the effect as in the picture. I want a button, what to display `"Item Name"` in `popup`. But my button is not displayed.

The problem is that this nature of my table is a dynamic (form `JSON`) - which makes things difficult.

**Picture:**
[image]

```js
var $table = $('#table');
var mydata = [{
    "id": 0,
    "name": "test0",
    "price": "$0"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "test1",
    "price": "$1"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "test2",
    "price": "$2"
  }
];

$(function() {
  $('#table').bootstrapTable({
    data: mydata
  });
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.10.1/bootstrap-table.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflarenter code heree.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.10.1/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <table id="table" data-search="true">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th data-field="id" data-sortable="true">Item ID</th>
          <th data-field="name" data-sortable="true">Item Name</th>
          <th data-field="price" data-sortable="true">Item Price</th>
          <th>Show Name</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Small button</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I will be grateful for your help.

Comment: So, you would like to have a popup (modal) opened when you click on Item name?

Comment: Yes, popup. But after button click. After click button 1st show test0, after click button 2st show test1 and so on

Comment: Hi, is this somewhat what you need? https://jsfiddle.net/tmyfssw2/. I did not add the CSS. So copy paste it :P

Comment: In static code, it's easy to do. The question is how to do this when reading from JSON?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hope this helps..

```
    <html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.10.1/bootstrap-table.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.10.1/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <table id="table" data-search="true">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th data-field="id" data-sortable="true">Item ID</th>
          <th data-field="name" data-sortable="true">Item Name</th>
          <th data-field="price" data-sortable="true">Item Price</th>
          <th>Show Name</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>

      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p></p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>


    <script>


            var $table = $('#table');
            var mydata = [{
                "id": 0,
                "name": "test0",
                "price": "$0"
              },
              {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "test1",
                "price": "$1"
              },
              {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "test2",
                "price": "$2"
              }
            ];

            $(function() {
              $('#table').bootstrapTable({
                data: mydata,
                columns: [ {},{},{},  
                {
                  field: 'operate',
                  title: 'Edit',
                  align: 'center',
                  valign: 'middle',
                  clickToSelect: false,
                  formatter : function(value,row,index) {
                    //return '<input name="elementname"  value="'+value+'"/>';
                    return '<button class=\'btn btn-primary \' pageName="'+row.name+'" pageDetails="'+row.price+'"  >Edit</button> ';
                  }
                }
              ]               
              });


            $(".btn").click(function(){
                var pageDetails = $(this).attr('pageDetails');
                var pageName = $(this).attr('pageName');
                $(".modal .modal-title").html(pageName);
                $(".modal .modal-body").html(pageDetails);
                $(".modal").modal("show");

            });

            });




    </script>




</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Could you explain what you’re doing instead of just posting a possiblr answer? So OP and others could learn from your code

Comment: I added code to add the column in your data table. The formatter adds the column that contains the button. Button data attributes contain the information to be used in the modal. $. Btn click function grabs the data attributes on button click and then passes them to the modal. Hope this explains...

Comment: Yes sir! This is clear :) But this time, I ask about "Could you explain what you’re doing instead of just posting a possiblr answer?" :)

Comment: Well ... actually you are not doing anything wrong.. You are not just doing it!! In your function to initiate bootstrap table, I added the code to add a column for each row , added modal code and added the jquery function to populate modal with relevant information on each button click.  And this really is the best I am at giving explanations...