# Adding delete button to bootstrapTable in MVC

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a .Net MVC project that fills a table with data using a bootstrapTable from bootstrap v3. I want to add a delete button to each row.

The bootstrapTable takes json data and loads it. The json is built like this:

```
public virtual JsonResult Search(FormCollection searchArgument)
{
    IEnumerable<MyData> myListData = GetMyListData(searchArgument);
    var jsonResult = Json(myListData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    return jsonResult;
}
```

So the jsonResult is just a list of all of my MyData. My view that shows the result looks like this:

```
@model MyNamespace.Web.Models.MyListViewModel
<div class="col-md-12">
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Index";
        Layout = MVC.Shared.Views._Layout;

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <form role="form" id="formsearch">
                    <input id="fromsearch" name="fromsearch" type="hidden" value="true" />
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Status, "Status:")<br />
                        @Html.DropDownList("status", new SelectList(Model.Status, "Value", "Key", Model.SelectedStatus), new { @class = "selectButton" })
                    </div>
                    <input type="button" id="btnsearch" value="Search" />
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <table id="table" class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th data-field="MyDataNumber" data-sortable="true">Number</th>
                            <th data-field="MyDataCreatedate" data-sortable="true">Created</th>
                            <th data-field="Status" data-sortable="true">Status</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
<script>

    $("#btnsearch").click(function () {
        $('#table').bootstrapTable('showLoading');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "@Url.Action(MVC.MyController.ActionNames.Search, MVC.MyController.Name)",   
            data: $('#formsearch').serialize(),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                $('#table').bootstrapTable('hideLoading');
                $('#table').bootstrapTable({
                    data: data,
                    striped: true,
                    pagination: true,
                    pageSize: 25,
                    pageList: [10, 25, 50, 100, 200],
                    search: false
                });
                $('#table').bootstrapTable('load', data).on('click-row.bs.table', function (e, row, $element) {
                    Showdetail(JSON.stringify(row));
                });
            },
            error: function (err) {
                console.log(err)
            }
        });
    });

    function Showdetail(jsonrow) {
        var obj = JSON.parse(jsonrow);
            window.location = "@Url.Action(MVC.MyController.ActionNames.ShowMyData, MVC.MyData.Name)?myDataId=" + obj.Id;
    }


</script>

@section AddToHead 
{
    @Styles.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap-table/css")
}

@section scripts 
{
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap-table")
}
```

So the javascript function `("#btnsearch").click` gets the json data from `public virtual JsonResult Search` and sends that to `bootstrapTable` which loads the data in the table. What I want to do is to add a new header in my table, like this:

```
<table id="table" class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-field="MyDataNumber" data-sortable="true">Number</th>
            <th data-field="MyDataCreatedate" data-sortable="true">Created</th>
            <th data-field="Status" data-sortable="true">Status</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

And then in the last column add a delete button that has the id of that row (`@Model.Id` for instance) so that I can call the controller to delete the row from the database and then reload the table so that the row also disappears from the GUI.

I could easily do it with an `ActionLink` but since I don't loop through all objects and then draw them out on the page, I can't just add an `ActionLink` to the page. All the rendering of the rows is done in the bootstrapTable.

I looked at this question and answer and it seemed promising but it's not quite what I'm doing and I can't get my head around what I would need to do to get it working for me: [Bootstrap table - dynamic button in row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46516001/bootstrap-table-dynamic-button-in-row).

Answer (score 1):

According to documantation and examples here:
https://live.bootstrap-table.com/example/column-options/events.html

Add to your scripts:

```
<script>
  var $table = $('#table')

  function operateFormatter(value, row, index) {
    return [

      '<a class="remove" href="javascript:void(0)" title="Remove">',
      '<i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Delete',
      '</a>'
    ].join('')
  }

  window.operateEvents = {

    'click .remove': function (e, value, row, index) {

//edit here for ajax request to delete row.id record

    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "@Url.Action(MVC.MyController.ActionNames.Delete,MVC.MyController.Name)",   
            data: {id:row.id},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
              //when success remove row
      $table.bootstrapTable('remove', {
        field: 'id',
        values: [row.id]
      })
            },
            error: function (err) {
                console.log(err)
            }
        });



    }
  }
</script>
```

and edit your html table:

```
<table id="table" class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-field="MyDataNumber" data-sortable="true">Number</th>
            <th data-field="MyDataCreatedate" data-sortable="true">Created</th>
            <th data-field="Status" data-sortable="true">Status</th>
             <th data-field="operate" data-formatter="operateFormatter" data-events="operateEvents">Actions</th> <!--add this col-->
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I can't get this to work, however. The example code you provided doesn't seem to be for bootstrap v3 because things like "class fa fa-trash" doesn't exist. But I tested it like this instead: 

$(function operateFormatter(value, row, index) {
        return '<a href="javascript:void(0)" title="Remove"></a>'
    });

    $(window.operateEvents = {
        'click .remove': function (e, value, row, index) {
            alert('You clicked remove action, row: ' + JSON.stringify(row))
        }
    });

BootstrapTable only returns "-" on that row ("undefinedText").

Comment: When I wrote "BootstrapTable only returns '-' on that row", I meant in that column. In BootstrapTable.DEFAULTS '-' stands for undefinedText, so that's what's being returned, despite of the data-formatter.

Comment: I upgraded to bootstrap v4 to see if I can get this to work there, but then the entire site css was destroyed, so I had to go back to v3. :(