# How to add View/Delete button to HTML Table loaded from JSON Data

Tags: javascript, html

I have a plain HTML Javascript table and I am loading data from a javascript file which contains the data in a JSON format.
Everything seems to work perfectly fine.
Now I want to add two buttons View and Delete which when clicked will go to another page or execute another javascript function. Can someone help me figure out how to add the button in the given code.

HTML Code :

```
        <table class="table-striped border-success">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th data-field="id">
                        <span class="text-success">
                            ID
                        </span>
                    </th>
                    <th data-field="fName">
                        <span class="text-success">
                            First Name
                        </span>
                    </th>
                    <th data-field="lName">
                        <span class="text-success">
                            Last Name
                        </span>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>

    <!-- Include the file where the JSON data is stored -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            // Use the given data to create 
            // the table and display it
            $('table').bootstrapTable({
                data: mydata
            });
        });

        // Parse the imported data as JSON
        // and store it
        var mydata = JSON.parse(da)
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Test.js (Javascript code which contains JSON Data):

```
var da = `[
    { "id": "24323", 
      "fName": "Mark ", 
      "lName": "Smith" },
    { "id": "24564",
      "fName": "Caitlin", 
      "lName": "MacDonald" }
]`;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the 2 buttons something like this

```
 <table class="table-striped border-success">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th data-field="id">
                    <span class="text-success">
                        ID
                    </span>
                </th>
                <th data-field="fName">
                    <span class="text-success">
                        First Name
                    </span>
                </th>
                <th data-field="lName">
                    <span class="text-success">
                        Last Name
                    </span>
                </th>
                <th data-field="view">
                    <span class="text-success">
                        View
                    </span>
                </th>
                <th data-field="delete">
                    <span class="text-success">
                        Delete
                    </span>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>
<!-- Include the file where the JSON data is stored -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        // Use the given data to create 
        // the table and display it
        $('table').bootstrapTable({
            data: mydata,
            columns:[{},{},{},
            {
              field: 'operate',
              title: 'View',
              align: 'center',
              valign: 'middle',
              clickToSelect: false,
              formatter : function(value,row,index) {
                return '<button type=\'button\' onclick=\'gotoPage()\'>View</button>';
              },
            {
              field: 'operate',
              title: 'Delete',
              align: 'center',
              valign: 'middle',
              clickToSelect: false,
              formatter : function(value,row,index) {
                return '<button type=\'button\' onclick=\'delete()\'>Delete</button>';
              }
        });
    });
    
    function gotToPage(){
       window.location.href = '/somepage'
    }

    function delete(){
       // Your delete functionality
    }

    // Parse the imported data as JSON
    // and store it
    var mydata = JSON.parse(da)
</script>
```

Comment: I want the buttons for each index of table .. say there are 10 records then I need the buttons for each of those 10 records

Comment: I have updated my code. You can also refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46516001/bootstrap-table-dynamic-button-in-row