# jQuery - loop over select tag base on row location

Tags: jquery, loops, select, html-table, each

How can I loop over the select tag options base on the selected row. Please see my screenshot

[image]

Once the user click the update button I need to loop over the the 3 select tags options that are located on the selected row.
I have this code already dealing with select event.

```
$('select.selectedsystem').on('change', function () {
        var selectedText = $(this).val();
        var user = $(this).parents('td').prev().text();
        var syslvl = $(this).parents('td').next();
        var sysbranch = $(this).parents('td').nextAll().eq(1);
        var sysunit = $(this).parents('td').nextAll().eq(2)
        syslvl.text("Retrieving...");
        sysbranch.text("Retrieving...");
        sysunit.text("Retrieving...");

    }).change();
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is a form, then you can loop through the form elements using each loop and the form id.

See the code below

```
$("#form :select").each(function(){
        // Your stuff
});
```

Comment: hi, no it's not a form i only have table.

Comment: You can loop through the table itself, Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3065342/how-do-i-iterate-through-table-rows-and-cells-in-javascript

Comment: yes, but my question is during loop when i encounter the select tag how can i loop over the items inside the select tag.

Comment: Use jquery itself to select the select inside the table data (td)

Comment: Is there any id related to that select?

Comment: no as of now but i can set an id but id should be unique i can add maybe a class?

Comment: Sure ,select the element with the help of classes. Refer https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_selectors.asp