# Click a button and get values of cells in same row with JavaScript (or jquery)

Tags: javascript, python, flask, html-table, jinja2

So I created an html-table with a for loop containing a list of objects from my python application. I now want to implement a delete function and for that I need to get the values of the cells from the same row where the button was clicked.
I would prefer to do it in JavaScript, not jquery as I don't have any experience with that

```
<table class="table" id="table">
<tr>
    <th scope="col">#</th>
    <th scope="col">Titel</th>
    <th scope="col">Interpret</th>
</tr>

{% for song in songs %}
<tr>

    <td>{{song.id}}</td>
    <td>{{song.titel}}</td>
    <td>{{song.interpret}}</td>
    <td>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" id="delete_button" name="delete_button" onclick="get_values(this)">Delete</button>
    </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

**EDIT:**
I looked up those .parentNode and .previousSibling @Barmar mentioned and tried to write a function for the existing onclick="get_values(this)" I already added to the buttons above

```
<script>
function get_values(this) {
var td = this.parentNode;
var x = td.previousSibling.innerHTML;
console.log(x);
}
</script>
```

The console.log response said: "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: get_values"

**EDIT 2:**

So I finally made progress with avoiding the ReferenceError. I was trying function get_values(this) which wasn't allowed, so I changed it to function get_values(x).

```
<script>
function get_values(x) {
    var td = x.parentNode;
    interpret = td.previousSibling;
    interpret_value = interpret.innerHTML;
    titel = interpret.previousSibling.previousSibling.innerHTML;

    console.log(titel);
    console.log(interpret_value);
    }
</script>
</body>
```

The problem I now have is that the code actually actually works without the .innerHTML properties. So I am actually getting back e.g. last Christmas and wham!. But now I struggle with just getting the values without the td-tags. I tried it with .value aswell.

**EDIT 3:**
Okay, I guess there's been a little mistake, I sorted it out by myself now, here's the code I am using now and it gives me the correct values. I still don't really get why I need to use the double .previousSibling but aslong as it works, I'm fine. Thanks to everyone who tried to help, I really appreciate that. I wish you guys a Happy New Year.

```
<script>
function get_values(x) {
    var td = x.parentNode;
    interpret = td.previousSibling.previousSibling;
    interpret_value = interpret.innerHTML;
    titel = interpret.previousSibling.previousSibling;
    titel_value = titel.innerHTML;


    console.log(interpret);
    console.log(interpret_value);
    console.log(titel);
    console.log(titel_value);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Use `this.parentNode` to get the `td`, and then use `.previousSibling` to iterate through all the cells in the same row.

Comment: "submit" what? You don't have a form.

Comment: Did you already start to define a `get_values()` function? It may help to see what you started with

Comment: @Barmar I looked up on those but still couldn't make it. Could you please have a look on my edit and give me further information? :)

Comment: You should post the working solution in an Answer, not in the Question. You're allowed to answer your own question.

Comment: You need to use `previousSibling` twice because there are text nodes between the elements. Use `previousSiblingElement` and it will skip them, then you only need one.

Answer (score 0):

First off, assuming you already have a button, you would code the functionality of a button click like this.
(initialization of button in html for clarification):

```
<input type="button" id="deleteBtn" value="Delete">
```

Next, in the Javascript, you will add this code to make the button call a "delete" function when clicked (here I named the delete function "delCells"):

```
let delBtn = document.querySelector("#deleteBtn");
delBtn.addEventListener("click", delCells);
```

That is the code that will make a button dynamic (so that it will call a delete function upon being pressed)

Now, in that delete function,
If you would like to iterate through a series of items in a table using Javascript, you firstly identify the table as your node:

`var table = document.getElementById("mytab1");`

Now that you have a node pointing to your table, you can simply iterate through it with a for loop:

`for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
 .... }`

Since you want to get the vales of all the elements in a row, you can create an array and store all of values in that, then process them into a hash and further as you decide:

```
let arr = []  //before the for loop
arr[i] = table.row[i]
```

Now, putting all of it together, in your action function (that is fired when you click the button), you'll have:

```
let arr = []
var table = document.getElementById("mytab1");
for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
  arr[i] = table.row[i]
}
```

At this point you'll have an array of all elements, so you can proceed with whatever you were trying to accomplish

View this link for more information on this topic: [How do I iterate through table rows and cells in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3065342/how-do-i-iterate-through-table-rows-and-cells-in-javascript)

Comment: but this will give me all cells of the whole table, so of all rows, right?
I just want to get the cells of that ONE row, where the button has been clicked. There is a button in each row, as it's in the {% for %}-loop swell, in case you missed that

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
Remove the type of the button, the type submit button in HTML causes the page to reload unnecessarily

```
<button class="btn btn-danger" id="delete_button" name="delete_button" onclick="get_values(this)">Delete</button
```

Add a click listener on your button:

```
document.getElementById("delete_button").onclick = function(this){
console.log(this)
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I put it right before the closing </body> tag and still got the same error, with both types of scripts

Comment: is the javascript code itself valid and am I referencing the onclick="get_values()" to my button correctly?

Comment: First you should remove the type of the button "type =" submit "", then test again if it gives the same error change your onclick to: "onclick =" alert ('testing if it will work') "

Comment: okay I tested this and the alert popped up. but deleting the submit-type doesn't seem to fix it all

Comment: Add the script at the end of the tags </ html>

Comment: Still the same response. No matter if I put it in the head, in the body or outside the body

Comment: okay I've seen the edit. And I think there's a problem. Because I am generating several buttons for each row with the for-loop, I don't think it's possible to assign them an id or if I do, it doesn't make sense