# How to loop through a HTML table with Javascript based on time

Tags: javascript, html, loops, csv, formatting

I am going through a list of data points collected from analyzing a sequence of available parking spaces using python. I have exported the results (about 5 days of data) as a csv and translated it into a HTML table.

I have been trying to loop thorugh the data, from oldest to latest, showcasing the time and spots available.

Since this is going to be on a webpage, I would like to only show one result at a time, going to the next result every 5 seconds (for demonstration purposes).

I have been trying to use javascript to implement this, but have fallen short of completing what I want.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```js
for (let row of mytab1.rows) 
{
    for(let cell of row.cells) 
    {
       console.log(cell.innerText)
    }
}
```

```html
<table id="mytab1">
<thead><tr><th title="Field #1">year</th>
<th title="Field #2">month</th>
<th title="Field #3">day</th>
<th title="Field #4">hour</th>
<th title="Field #5">minute</th>
<th title="Field #6">availability</th>
</tr></thead>
<tbody><tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">07</td>
<td align="right">09</td>
<td align="right">29</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">07</td>
<td align="right">39</td>
<td align="right">27</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">08</td>
<td align="right">09</td>
<td align="right">21</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">08</td>
<td align="right">39</td>
<td align="right">18</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">09</td>
<td align="right">09</td>
<td align="right">14</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">09</td>
<td align="right">39</td>
<td align="right">3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">09</td>
<td align="right">5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">39</td>
<td align="right">6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">09</td>
<td align="right">4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">39</td>
<td align="right">5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">09</td>
<td align="right">4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">39</td>
<td align="right">5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">13</td>
<td align="right">09</td>
<td align="right">9</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">13</td>
<td align="right">39</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">14</td>
<td align="right">09</td>
<td align="right">13</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">14</td>
<td align="right">39</td>
<td align="right">9</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">15</td>
<td align="right">09</td>
<td align="right">8</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">15</td>
<td align="right">39</td>
<td align="right">7</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">16</td>
<td align="right">09</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">16</td>
<td align="right">39</td>
<td align="right">14</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">17</td>
<td align="right">09</td>
<td align="right">18</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">22</td>
<td align="right">07</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">29</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">22</td>
<td align="right">07</td>
<td align="right">40</td>
<td align="right">27</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">22</td>
<td align="right">08</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">27</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">22</td>
<td align="right">08</td>
<td align="right">40</td>
<td align="right">22</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">22</td>
<td align="right">09</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">28</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">22</td>
<td align="right">09</td>
<td align="right">40</td>
<td align="right">28</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">22</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">28</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">22</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">40</td>
<td align="right">30</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">22</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">26</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">22</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">40</td>
<td align="right">27</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">22</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">30</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">22</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">40</td>
<td align="right">31</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">22</td>
<td align="right">13</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">30</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">22</td>
<td align="right">13</td>
<td align="right">40</td>
<td align="right">31</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">22</td>
<td align="right">14</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">28</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">22</td>
<td align="right">14</td>
<td align="right">40</td>
<td align="right">29</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">22</td>
<td align="right">15</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">24</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">22</td>
<td align="right">15</td>
<td align="right">40</td>
<td align="right">26</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">22</td>
<td align="right">16</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">30</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">22</td>
<td align="right">16</td>
<td align="right">40</td>
<td align="right">31</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">27</td>
<td align="right">07</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">27</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">27</td>
<td align="right">07</td>
<td align="right">40</td>
<td align="right">29</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">27</td>
<td align="right">08</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">25</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">27</td>
<td align="right">08</td>
<td align="right">40</td>
<td align="right">27</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">27</td>
<td align="right">09</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">16</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">27</td>
<td align="right">09</td>
<td align="right">40</td>
<td align="right">4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">27</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">27</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">40</td>
<td align="right">3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">27</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">27</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">40</td>
<td align="right">5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">27</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">27</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">40</td>
<td align="right">5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">27</td>
<td align="right">13</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">8</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">27</td>
<td align="right">13</td>
<td align="right">40</td>
<td align="right">8</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">27</td>
<td align="right">14</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">27</td>
<td align="right">14</td>
<td align="right">40</td>
<td align="right">8</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">27</td>
<td align="right">15</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">7</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">27</td>
<td align="right">15</td>
<td align="right">40</td>
<td align="right">8</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">27</td>
<td align="right">16</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">27</td>
<td align="right">16</td>
<td align="right">40</td>
<td align="right">14</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">07</td>
<td align="right">41</td>
<td align="right">27</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">08</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">27</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">08</td>
<td align="right">41</td>
<td align="right">17</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">09</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">17</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">09</td>
<td align="right">41</td>
<td align="right">4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">41</td>
<td align="right">5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">41</td>
<td align="right">2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">41</td>
<td align="right">2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">13</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">7</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">13</td>
<td align="right">41</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">14</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">9</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">14</td>
<td align="right">41</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">15</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">15</td>
<td align="right">41</td>
<td align="right">7</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">16</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">16</td>
<td align="right">41</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">17</td>
<td align="right">07</td>
<td align="right">48</td>
<td align="right">26</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">17</td>
<td align="right">08</td>
<td align="right">18</td>
<td align="right">26</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">17</td>
<td align="right">08</td>
<td align="right">48</td>
<td align="right">19</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">17</td>
<td align="right">09</td>
<td align="right">18</td>
<td align="right">20</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">17</td>
<td align="right">09</td>
<td align="right">48</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">17</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">18</td>
<td align="right">4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">17</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">48</td>
<td align="right">2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">17</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">18</td>
<td align="right">2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">17</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">48</td>
<td align="right">1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">17</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">18</td>
<td align="right">1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">17</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">48</td>
<td align="right">4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">17</td>
<td align="right">13</td>
<td align="right">18</td>
<td align="right">7</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">17</td>
<td align="right">13</td>
<td align="right">48</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">17</td>
<td align="right">14</td>
<td align="right">18</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">17</td>
<td align="right">14</td>
<td align="right">48</td>
<td align="right">6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">17</td>
<td align="right">15</td>
<td align="right">18</td>
<td align="right">8</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">17</td>
<td align="right">15</td>
<td align="right">48</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">17</td>
<td align="right">16</td>
<td align="right">18</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">17</td>
<td align="right">16</td>
<td align="right">48</td>
<td align="right">13</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this script

```
    const table =document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];
    const tbody = table.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
    const tbodyRows = tbody.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for (let j=0, max=tbodyRows.length; j < max; j++) {
     let singleRow = tbodyRows[j];
     let singleRowDate = [];    
     for (let i=0;i<singleRow.getElementsByTagName("td").length;i++){
        singleRowDate= [...singleRowDate,singleRow.getElementsByTagName("td")[i].innerText];
     };
     singleRowDate = singleRowDate.join("-");
     console.log(singleRowDate);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want accessing each cell by javascript you can check below Stack Overflow answer:
[How do I iterate through table rows and cells in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3065342/how-do-i-iterate-through-table-rows-and-cells-in-javascript)

And for control the time of reading the cell you could use "setTimeout Or setInterval" javascript functions 
based on your business Logic

Comment: I've looked into that, but I couldn't isolate a given entry

Comment: what did you mean by given entry ?

Comment: As I loop over each cell (tr), I would like to display the data and available spots. Then after, 5 seconds, loop to the next cell (tr) and display its contents until the last cell (tr)

Comment: cell is represented by <td> not <tr> so each row has (n) of cells so, the outer loop for the table rows and the inner loop for the inner rows . any way see the below code (it's not tested but I hope find it helpful ):                                         :let temp=0;
while (i < table.length){
temp=i;
for(let cell of row.cells) 
   {
      console.log(cell.innerText)
}
i=table.length+1;
setTimeout(function(){
i=temp;
i++;
},5000)
}

Answer (score 0):

I would say this should fit. Of course you need to display the one entry somehow and also handle what should happen if it reaches the end of the table.

```js
let currentRow = mytab1.rows[1]
setInterval(function() {
    let tdTexts = []
    Array.from(currentRow.getElementsByTagName("td")).forEach(function(element){
        tdTexts = [...tdTexts, element.innerText]
    })      
    console.log(tdTexts)
    currentRow = currentRow.nextElementSibling; // goto next row
}, 5000);
```

```html
<table id="mytab1">
<thead><tr><th title="Field #1">year</th>
<th title="Field #2">month</th>
<th title="Field #3">day</th>
<th title="Field #4">hour</th>
<th title="Field #5">minute</th>
<th title="Field #6">availability</th>
</tr></thead>
<tbody><tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">07</td>
<td align="right">09</td>
<td align="right">29</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">07</td>
<td align="right">39</td>
<td align="right">27</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">08</td>
<td align="right">09</td>
<td align="right">21</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">08</td>
<td align="right">39</td>
<td align="right">18</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">09</td>
<td align="right">09</td>
<td align="right">14</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">09</td>
<td align="right">39</td>
<td align="right">3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">09</td>
<td align="right">5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">39</td>
<td align="right">6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">09</td>
<td align="right">4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">39</td>
<td align="right">5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">09</td>
<td align="right">4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">39</td>
<td align="right">5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">13</td>
<td align="right">09</td>
<td align="right">9</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">13</td>
<td align="right">39</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">14</td>
<td align="right">09</td>
<td align="right">13</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">14</td>
<td align="right">39</td>
<td align="right">9</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">15</td>
<td align="right">09</td>
<td align="right">8</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">15</td>
<td align="right">39</td>
<td align="right">7</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">16</td>
<td align="right">09</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">16</td>
<td align="right">39</td>
<td align="right">14</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">17</td>
<td align="right">09</td>
<td align="right">18</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">22</td>
<td align="right">07</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">29</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">22</td>
<td align="right">07</td>
<td align="right">40</td>
<td align="right">27</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">22</td>
<td align="right">08</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">27</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">22</td>
<td align="right">08</td>
<td align="right">40</td>
<td align="right">22</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">22</td>
<td align="right">09</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">28</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">22</td>
<td align="right">09</td>
<td align="right">40</td>
<td align="right">28</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">22</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">28</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">22</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">40</td>
<td align="right">30</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">22</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">26</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">22</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">40</td>
<td align="right">27</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">22</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">30</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">22</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">40</td>
<td align="right">31</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">22</td>
<td align="right">13</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">30</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">22</td>
<td align="right">13</td>
<td align="right">40</td>
<td align="right">31</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">22</td>
<td align="right">14</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">28</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">22</td>
<td align="right">14</td>
<td align="right">40</td>
<td align="right">29</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">22</td>
<td align="right">15</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">24</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">22</td>
<td align="right">15</td>
<td align="right">40</td>
<td align="right">26</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">22</td>
<td align="right">16</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">30</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">22</td>
<td align="right">16</td>
<td align="right">40</td>
<td align="right">31</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">27</td>
<td align="right">07</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">27</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">27</td>
<td align="right">07</td>
<td align="right">40</td>
<td align="right">29</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">27</td>
<td align="right">08</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">25</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">27</td>
<td align="right">08</td>
<td align="right">40</td>
<td align="right">27</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">27</td>
<td align="right">09</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">16</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">27</td>
<td align="right">09</td>
<td align="right">40</td>
<td align="right">4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">27</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">27</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">40</td>
<td align="right">3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">27</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">27</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">40</td>
<td align="right">5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">27</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">27</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">40</td>
<td align="right">5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">27</td>
<td align="right">13</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">8</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">27</td>
<td align="right">13</td>
<td align="right">40</td>
<td align="right">8</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">27</td>
<td align="right">14</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">27</td>
<td align="right">14</td>
<td align="right">40</td>
<td align="right">8</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">27</td>
<td align="right">15</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">7</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">27</td>
<td align="right">15</td>
<td align="right">40</td>
<td align="right">8</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">27</td>
<td align="right">16</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">27</td>
<td align="right">16</td>
<td align="right">40</td>
<td align="right">14</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">07</td>
<td align="right">41</td>
<td align="right">27</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">08</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">27</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">08</td>
<td align="right">41</td>
<td align="right">17</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">09</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">17</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">09</td>
<td align="right">41</td>
<td align="right">4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">41</td>
<td align="right">5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">41</td>
<td align="right">2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">41</td>
<td align="right">2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">13</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">7</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">13</td>
<td align="right">41</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">14</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">9</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">14</td>
<td align="right">41</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">15</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">15</td>
<td align="right">41</td>
<td align="right">7</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">16</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">16</td>
<td align="right">41</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">17</td>
<td align="right">07</td>
<td align="right">48</td>
<td align="right">26</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">17</td>
<td align="right">08</td>
<td align="right">18</td>
<td align="right">26</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">17</td>
<td align="right">08</td>
<td align="right">48</td>
<td align="right">19</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">17</td>
<td align="right">09</td>
<td align="right">18</td>
<td align="right">20</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">17</td>
<td align="right">09</td>
<td align="right">48</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">17</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">18</td>
<td align="right">4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">17</td>
<td align="right">10</td>
<td align="right">48</td>
<td align="right">2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">17</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">18</td>
<td align="right">2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">17</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
<td align="right">48</td>
<td align="right">1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">17</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">18</td>
<td align="right">1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">17</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">48</td>
<td align="right">4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">17</td>
<td align="right">13</td>
<td align="right">18</td>
<td align="right">7</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">17</td>
<td align="right">13</td>
<td align="right">48</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">17</td>
<td align="right">14</td>
<td align="right">18</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">17</td>
<td align="right">14</td>
<td align="right">48</td>
<td align="right">6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">17</td>
<td align="right">15</td>
<td align="right">18</td>
<td align="right">8</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">17</td>
<td align="right">15</td>
<td align="right">48</td>
<td align="right">11</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">17</td>
<td align="right">16</td>
<td align="right">18</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td align="right">12</td>
<td align="right">17</td>
<td align="right">16</td>
<td align="right">48</td>
<td align="right">13</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
```