# How to SUM the inputs inside all rows?

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, javascript-objects

I'm using a script to generate a new row with value each time, those values goes to a table as an input
All what I want is a button to sum all values in those inputs in one input.

Total input id is valueall

This is the code I have used:

```
            function updateSubTotal() { 
            var table = document.getElementById("empTable");
            for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
                for (var cell; cell = row.cells[1];){
                var inp = cell.children[0];
                }
             }     
             document.getElementById("valueall").value = inp.value;
            }
```

That code works fine when I put it under **var inp = cell.children[0];** but it keeps repeating the same row value as loop.

Here's the table:

```
 <form>
        <table id="empTable">
            <tr>
                <td>Products in the invoice</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
 </form>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I iterate through table rows and cells in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3065342/how-do-i-iterate-through-table-rows-and-cells-in-javascript)

Comment: @kmoser Unfortunately I already saw that answer, it doesn't work with inputs (children).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not summing anything. You need to actually sum up the contents of the `<input>` fields:

```
function updateSubTotal() { 
  var sum = 0;
  var table = document.getElementById("empTable");
  for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
    for (var cell; cell = row.cells[1];){
      var inp = cell.children[0];
      sum += Number(inp.value)
    }
  }     
  document.getElementById("valueall").value = sum;
}
```