# Can't loop through table in javascript

Tags: javascript, datatables

I am new to javascript and am currently trying to loop through table rows to get the data from it however its showing an error that it can't recognize `rows` for `table`.

```html
 <div class="row" id="tablediv">
        <div class="col">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="table"/>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```js
    var table = document.getElementById('#table');

for (let i in table.rows) {
       let row = table.rows[i];
       //iterate through rows
       //rows would be accessed using the "row" variable assigned in the for loop
        console.log(row);
       for (let j in row.cells) {
         let col = row.cells[j];
         //iterate through columns
         //columns would be accessed using the "col" variable assigned in the for loop
           console.log(col);
       }
    }
```

```js
offices:1048 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'rows')
    at save (offices:1048:25)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (offices:101:84)
```

Am I doing something wrong or is there a workaround for that?

Comment: As the error says, you are trying to read the `rows` property on a null object. So `table` is null when you start your loop. How are you setting the `table` variable?

Answer (score 1):

Your table variable must be declare before.
You can do this :

```
<table id="myTab1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">First</th>
        <th scope="col">Last</th>
        <th scope="col">Handle</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="rowTable">
        <td>Mark</td>
        <td>Otto</td>
        <td>@mdo</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="rowTable">
        <td>Jacob</td>
        <td>Thornton</td>
        <td>@fat</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="rowTable">
        <td>Larry</td>
        <td>the Bird</td>
        <td>@twitter</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<script>
var table = document.getElementById("myTab1");
for (let i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
    let row = table.rows[i]
    for (let j = 0; j < row.cells.length; j++) {
        let cell = row.cells[j];
        console.log(cell.textContent)
    }  
}
```

Comment: thanks, that worked! But this gets the whole `select` dropdown options not the selected one. Is there a way to filter this out?

Answer (score 0):

You have to target the table first. With `var table = document.getElementById("myTable");`, you can store in a variable table and then loop through.

In your example, this would look like `var table = document.getElementById("table");`

Also check this [How do I iterate through table rows and cells in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3065342/how-do-i-iterate-through-table-rows-and-cells-in-javascript)

Comment: The table is already defined as you mentioned. I edited the question for clarity.

Comment: I see. Yes then you have to add the html tags `<tr>` `<td>`