# How to iterate through this html table and get data from rows whose last col is not empty?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, web-applications

I've been trying to get this data, but the array comes out empty:

```
function saveData() {
  var tableData = [];
  var table = document.getElementById("dtable");
  console.log(table)

  for (var i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
    let tableCells = table.rows.item(i).cells;
    let cellLength = tableCells.length;

    for (let j = 0; j < cellLength; j++) {
      let cellVal = tableCells.item(j).innerHTML;
      tableData.push(cellVal)
    }
  }
  console.log(tableData)
  rows = JSON.stringify(tableData);
  google.script.run.formToSheets(rows);
}
```

Thanks for any help!
[image]

Comment: Related: [How do I iterate through table rows and cells in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3065342/1595451)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your script, as one of several possible modifications, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var tableData = [];
var table = document.getElementById("dtable");
console.log(table)

for (var i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
  let tableCells = table.rows.item(i).cells;
  let cellLength = tableCells.length;

  for (let j = 0; j < cellLength; j++) {
    let cellVal = tableCells.item(j).innerHTML;
    tableData.push(cellVal)
  }
}
console.log(tableData)
```

#### To:

```
var table = document.getElementById("dtable");
console.log(table)

var [, ...tr] = table.querySelectorAll("tr");
var tableData = [...tr].map(r => {
  var td = r.querySelectorAll("td");
  return [...td].map((c, j) => j != 3 ? c.innerHTML : c.querySelectorAll("select")[0].value);
});
console.log(tableData)
```

- In this modification, from a table, the table rows are retrieved. And, the table cells are retrieved from the table rows. In teh case of the dropdown list, the value is retrieved from the dropdown list.

#### Note:

- When this modification was not the direct solution to your issue, I think that when you provide your whole script, it will help to correctly understand your question.

Comment: @santosOnit Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.